# Get contained type in a List<T> through reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Through reflection, is there some way for me to look at a generic List's contained type to see what type the collection is of?  For example:

I have a simple set of business objects that derive from an interface, like this:

```
public interface IEntityBase{}  

public class BusinessEntity : IEntityBase   
{
    public IList<string> SomeStrings {get; set;}       
    public IList<ChildBusinessEntity> ChildEntities { get; set;}
} 

public class ChildBusinessEntity : IEntityBase{}
```

In the case where I am iterating through the properties of BusinessEntity through reflection, would there be a way for me to see if the objects nested inside those lists derived from IEntityBase?

**Pseudo**coded (badly) like this:

```
foreach(PropertyInfo info in typeof(BusinessEntity).GetProperties())
{
  if(info.PropertyType is GenericIList &&
     TheNestedTypeInThisList.IsAssignableFrom(IEntityBase)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Only option I've heard so far, that works, would be to pull out the first item from that list, then look at its type.  Any easier way (especially because I can't be guaranteed that the List won't be empty)?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528546/type-getinterface-and-nested-types

Comment: Not a dupe: that question's asking about nested types, whereas this one (in spite of the title) seems to be asking about a generic type.

Comment: Oops, you're right, my bad :P

Comment: I don't see any nested type here; you should change the title.

Comment: My bad.  I was calling it "nested" because I didn't know what else to call it until I realize that it has a different connotation.  Title changed.  Either way, ChrisW found what I was looking for.   Makes sense in retrospect too...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# generic list <T> how to get the type of T?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming you have the `System.Type` which describes your `List<>`, you can use the `Type.GetGenericArguments()` method to get the `Type` instance which describes what it's a list of.

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info 
                                       in typeof(BusinessEntity).GetProperties())
{
    if (info.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
        info.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("IList") &&
        info.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Length > 0 &&
        info.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(string)
        )
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```