# How can I encrypt data that is saved to a file by DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-8, datacontractserializer

I'm creating a windows 8 store application with C#.
The app uses some webservices to get its data. The app saves some of the received data in a file using a `DataContractSerializer` and a `Dictionary`. This is done to cache some data that won't change too much.

The data is written to a file in the users local storage as a human readable xml.

Is there an easy way to save the data **encrypted**? I don't care what encryption algorithm is used, it just shouldn't be readable xml anymore.

Thanks in advance!

This is the code I use for saving the Dictionary to the file:

```
private static async Task InternalSaveAsync()
{
    StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(Filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (IRandomAccessStream sessionRandomAccess = await sessionFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (IOutputStream sessionOutputStream = sessionRandomAccess.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
        {
            DataContractSerializer sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), KnownTypes);
            sessionSerializer.WriteObject(sessionOutputStream.AsStreamForWrite(), _data);
            await sessionOutputStream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. I am not familiar with these APIs. I'll have to get acquainted, but in the meantime maybe this [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225174/using-datacontractserializer-and-dataprotectionprovider-to-serialize-and-encrypt) can help.

Comment: Duplicate of [Using DataContractSerializer and DataProtectionProvider to serialize and encrypt an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225174/using-datacontractserializer-and-dataprotectionprovider-to-serialize-and-encrypt) - thanks to @JuanAyala.

Comment: I believe DataProtectionProvider is available only for Windows8. So the question could still be valid. OP, what is the OS that you are targetting?

Comment: @ryadavilli question and tag state this is about Windows 8.

Comment: Oops missed that.My mistake. I could have sworn I did not see windows-8 there.

Comment: Yes, it's about Windows 8. I'm trying to use the methods mentioned by Juan Ayala. But sometimes I receive a AccessDenied Exception when file.OpenStreamForReadAsync() is executed. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Ok, i have it working now. The problem was me, accessing the files multiple times. I was just looking in the wrong section all the time. Thanks again @JuanAyala