# Confirm or deny: The XmlSerializer cannot serialize the following: arrays of ArrayList and arrays of List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xmlserializer

The documentation for the [XmlSerializer.Serialize method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdxxw552.aspx) states the following:

> The `XmlSerializer` cannot serialize the following: arrays of `ArrayList` and arrays of `List<T>`.

However if I try with the following code it works (I am use `List<int>` and `ArrayList`). So is this a documentation defect, a new feature in .NET 4.5 that hasn't made it's way to documentation?

I had suspected that it could be an abbreviated message about how you cannot serialise a `List<T>` unless you have [all the types in object graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704807/c-sharp-xmlserializer-serialize-generic-list-of-interface), but that doesn't make sense for ArrayList which is just `object`.

```
private static string Serialise<T>(T o)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, o);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant parts of the classes involved. Right now it's unclear what you're talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the documentation again - it says you can't serialize *arrays* of `List<T>` or `ArrayList` (i.e. `List<T>[]` and `ArrayList[]`).

Sure enough, these work:

```
Serialise(new ArrayList());
Serialise(new List<int>());
```

These do not:

```
Serialise(new ArrayList[]{});
Serialise(new List<int>[]{});
```

The latter throw this exception:

> `System.InvalidOperationException:` Unable to generate a temporary class `(result=1)`.