# I can't serialize a list of objects in C# with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a list of many test implements the interface IDoTest, that I want to store in a file. I also want to read from this file.

It seemed natural to simple use the **XmlSerializer** to store the objects in my List of IDoTest. But when I do this I get a vague  I am sorry I cant do that error in the neighborhood of  System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()

Can the XmlSerializer only do trivial jobs? Or am I missing something? They are talking about [custom serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) at MSDN. 
Here is my simplified code example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface IDoTest
    {
        void DoTest();
        void Setup();
    }
    internal class TestDBConnection : IDoTest
    {
        public string DBName;
        public void DoTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DoHardComplicated Test");
        }
        public void Setup()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SetUpDBTest");
        }
    }
    internal class PingTest : IDoTest
    {
        public string ServerName;
        public void DoTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MaybeDoAPing");
        }
        public void Setup()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SetupAPingTest");
        }
    }     

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TestDBConnection Do1 = new TestDBConnection { DBName = "SQLDB" };
            PingTest Do2 = new PingTest { ServerName = "AccTestServ_5" };
            List<IDoTest> allTest = new List<IDoTest> { Do1, (Do2) };
            // Now I want to serialize my list. 
            // Its here where I get the error at allTest
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(allTest.GetType());
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("mySerializedTestSuite.xml");
            x.Serialize(writer, allTest); 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` cannot serialize an `interface`, and by extension, it cannot serialize a `List<>` of some interface. It can only serialize concrete object types.

The assumption is that you will probably want to *deserialize* the objects at some point, and if it only output information pertaining to that interface, it can't guarantee that all the necessary data is present to reconstruct the original objects.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705115/120955) shows a potential workaround, if you are able to use an abstract base class and explicitly provide every possible type of object that may appear in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the link that StriplingWarrior gave and found this excellent answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15089253/648076 from [webturner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350188/webturner)

I changed his implementation and made a class class ListOfToDo that implemented both  List and IXmlSerializable. That worked! 
Here is my changed code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface IDoTest
    {
        void DoTest();
        void Setup();
    }
    public class TestDBConnection : IDoTest
    {
        public string DBName;
        public void DoTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DoHardComplicated Test");
        }
        public void Setup()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SetUpDBTest");
        }
    }
    public class PingTest : IDoTest
    {
        public string ServerName;
        public void DoTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MaybeDoAPing");
        }
        public void Setup()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SetupAPingTest");
        }
    }

    public class ListOfToDo : List<IDoTest>, **IXmlSerializable**
    {    
        #region IXmlSerializable
        public XmlSchema GetSchema(){ return null; }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)

           {
               reader.ReadStartElement("ListOfToDo");
               while (reader.IsStartElement("IDoTest"))
            {
                Type type = Type.GetType(reader.GetAttribute("AssemblyQualifiedName"));
                XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(type);

                reader.ReadStartElement("IDoTest");
                this.Add((IDoTest)serial.Deserialize(reader));
                reader.ReadEndElement(); //IDoTest
            }
            reader.ReadEndElement(); //IDoTest
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            foreach (IDoTest test in this)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("IDoTest");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("AssemblyQualifiedName", test.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(test.GetType());
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, test);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
         #endregion
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TestDBConnection Do1 = new TestDBConnection { DBName = "SQLDB" };
            PingTest Do2 = new PingTest { ServerName = "AccTestServ_5" };
            ListOfToDo allTest = new ListOfToDo { Do1, (Do2) };

            // Now I want to serialize my list. 
            // Its here where I get the error at allTest
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(allTest.GetType());
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("mySerializedTestSuite.xml");
            x.Serialize(writer, allTest); 
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            //Read it aka deserialize
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListOfToDo));
                var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader("mySerializedTestSuite.xml"));
                ListOfToDo readWhatToTest = (ListOfToDo)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                xmlReader.Close();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Output will then be:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListOfToDo>
  <IDoTest AssemblyQualifiedName="ConsoleApplication1.TestDBConnection, ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <TestDBConnection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <DBName>SQLDB</DBName>
    </TestDBConnection>
  </IDoTest>
  <IDoTest AssemblyQualifiedName="ConsoleApplication1.PingTest, ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <PingTest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <ServerName>AccTestServ_5</ServerName>
    </PingTest>
  </IDoTest>
</ListOfToDo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might be the cause of your issue but on these two examples they do use `typeof(T)` instead of `T.GetType()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s92ee1.aspx

[I can't serialize a list of objects in C# with XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722978/i-cant-serialize-a-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp-with-xmlserializer)