# Cannot serialize member 'x' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[x]]

Tags: c#, .net, xml, generics, serialization

I am trying to serialize an object to XML using XmlSerializer

I am expecting to get something like this:

```
<user>
    <username>administrator</username>
    <email>administrator@email.com</email>
    <roles>
        <roleId>D3DCBCDA-AD61-4764-B5A1-057D654F1C26</roleId>
        <role>admin</role>
        <roleId>D4DCBCDA-AD61-4764-B5A1-057D654F1C26</roleId>
        <role>editor</role>
    </roles>
</user>
```

**Inner Exception**

> Cannot serialize member `'Model.DTO.UserDTO.role'` of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[Model.DTO.RoleDTO, Domain.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner exception for more details.

**StackTrace**

```
at System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.CheckSupportedMember(TypeDesc typeDesc, MemberInfo member, Type type)
at System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetPropertyModel(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
at System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetFieldModel(MemberInfo memberInfo)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
```

**Code**

```
IList<RoleDTO> rl = new List<RoleDTO>();

    rl.Add(new RoleDTO { roleId = new Guid("D3DCBCDA-AD61-4764-B5A1-057D654F1C26"), 
                         role = "admin" });
   rl.Add(new RoleDTO { roleId = new Guid("D4DCBCDA-AD61-4764-B5A1-057D654F1C26"), 
                         role = "editor" });


UserDTO user = new UserDTO 
             {
                username = "administrator",
                email = "administrator@email.com",
                role = rl
             };

 XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(xml.GetType());
 XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FisaxmlDTO));
 StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
 XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
 xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, user);
 var xmll = sww.ToString(); // Your xml
```

Model:

```
namespace Model.DTO
{
    public class UserDTO
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public IList<RoleDTO> role { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleDTO
    {
        public Guid roleId { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That's the inner exception

Comment: Inner Exceptions can themselves have inner exceptions: you need to go all the way down.

Comment: You need to drill down more. There is another inner exception.

Comment: @Richard still, the same inner exception

Comment: It's due to the `IList`. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704807/xmlserializer-serialize-generic-list-of-interface).

Comment: Note that `DataContractSerializer` can handle `IList<T>`.