# How to serialize a Class (having ICollection)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, xsd, entity-framework-6, xmlserializer

I have a VB class that contains an array of other VB classes. Then I serialize an object into xml using

```
Private Sub Serialize(myObject As Object, myObjectType As Type)

        Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(myObjectType)
        Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("D:\DataTest\myXMLFile.xml")
        ser.Serialize(myWriter, myObject)
        myWriter.Close()

End Sub
```

my Classes:

```
Public Class mySerializableClass

        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Adresse As String
        Public Property IdF As Integer
        Public Property ISC() As myInnerSerializableClass

End Class  

Public Class myInnerSerializableClass

        Public Property CNSS As String
        Public Property nom As String

End Class
```

Untill now everything works fine (and my xml files is created). But when I replace

```
Public Property ISC() As myInnerSerializableClass
```

With

```
Public Property ISC() As ICollection(Of myInnerSerializableCass)
```

I get an arror that reads : An error occurred during reflection of type 'myCustomNameSpace.mySerializableClass'

P.S. I need the ICollection for EF code first, or find a way to work with arrays in EF code first.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the [**`XmlArray`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**`XmlArrayItem`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes to the property so that the serializer knows that the property should be serialized as a list.

```
<XmlArray("ISC"), XmlArrayItem("myInnerSerializableClass")> _
Public Property ISC() As ICollection(Of myInnerSerializableCass)
```

**Read more**

- [**Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The Error persists, I think the problem is that ICollection is an interface.

Comment: @IsmailKarchi : [**Yup, you're right about that**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15089253/3740093). Is there any other collection/list type you can use? -- Also, must you use XML serialization? If not, Binary Serialization is an alternative.

Comment: The objectif behind this is to create xml file from sql data. Do you know any workaround to replace ICollection in the class (needed for EntityFrameWork code first)

Comment: @IsmailKarchi : I've never used EF, but from my understanding a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) should work. It implements the `ICollection(Of T)` interface.

Comment: Thank you @VisualVincent I replaced the `ICollection(Of T)` interface with a `List(Of T)` it worked well for EntityFrameWork but not for xml serialization because the related entities don't load. so I used the [**Eagerly Loading**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: @IsmailKarchi : Glad you found a solution! Good luck!