# How to implement IXmlSerializable for recursive tags in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, recursion, ixmlserializable

I wonder how to implement the method ReadXml of the IXmlSerializable interface when my XML contains recursive tags like in the following example:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<dform>
    <label name='label-a' text='A' dbpath='module/label-a'/>
    <textmemo name='textmemo-a' text='' dbpath='module/textmemo-a'/>
    <section name='section-a' text='' dbpath='module/section-a'>
        <textmemo name='textmemo-b' text='' dbpath='module/textmemo-b'/>
    </section>
    <section name='section-b' text='' dbpath='module/section-b'>
        <textmemo name='textmemo-c' text='' dbpath='module/textmemo-c'/>
        <label name='label-c' text='A' dbpath='module/label-c'/>
        <section name='section-c' text='' dbpath='module/section-c'>
            <label name='label-d' text='A' dbpath='module/label-d'/>
        </section>
    </section>
</dform>
```

The element `<section>` works like a container for all kind of elements, itself included.
I need to translate this structure into objects: a List of elements (objects) that contains other List objects when the element is a Section. So I've created the following Interface and Classes:

```
public interface IWidget
{       
    String type { get;}
    String name { get; set; }
    String labelCation { get; set; }
    String text { get; set; }
    String dbpath { get; set; }

}

class Textmemo : IWidget
{
    public String type { get; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String labelCation { get; set; }
    public String text { get; set; }
    public String dbpath { get; set; }
    public List<IWidget> subsection { get; set; }

    public Textmemo()
    {
        type = "CONTROL";
    }

}



class Label : IWidget
{
    public String type { get; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String labelCation { get; set; }
    public String text { get; set; }
    public String dbpath { get; set; }
    public List<IWidget> subsection { get; set; }

    public Label()
    {
        type = "LABEL";
    }
}

class Section : IWidget
{
    public String type { get; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String labelCation { get; set; }
    public String text { get; set; }
    public String dbpath { get; set; }
    public List<IWidget> subsection { get; set; }

    public Section()
    {
        type = "SECTION";
        subsection = new List<IWidget>();
    }
}
```

The Section class has one more property compared with the interface IWidget from which it inherits, that is the *subsection property*.

Then I was ready to move my steps starting from this example [XmlSerializer serialize generic List of interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704807/xmlserializer-serialize-generic-list-of-interface)

but I really don't understand how to manage the `<section>` element in my code, that, at the moment, it is nothing more than the signature of the class:

```
public class WidgetsList: List<IWidget>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public WidgetsList() : base() { }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {

    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {

    }

}
```

Thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: Why don't you let the system do the heavy lifting ?

Comment: I would be more than happy to do that; there is clearly something I don't understand about how IXmlSerializable works because I can't figure out how any element is assigned to the right section or subsection. I am missing something, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you wanting to implement `IXmlSerializable` yourself? You can use various attributes to have the framework do this for you. For example, define a base class (given all your implementations are the same):

```
public abstract class Widget
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public abstract string type { get;}
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string labelCation { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string text { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string dbpath { get; set; }
}
```

The attributes here specify that `type` and `labelCation` are ignored (as they don't exist in the XML). The rest are mapped to XML attributes (e.g. `name='abc'`).

You can then create your three sub-types:

```
public class Textmemo : Widget
{
    public override string type { get; } = "CONTROL";
}

public class Label : Widget
{
    public override string type { get; } = "LABEL";
}

public class Section : Widget
{
    public override string type { get; } = "SECTION";

    [XmlElement("textmemo", Type=typeof(Textmemo))]
    [XmlElement("label", Type=typeof(Label))]
    [XmlElement("section", Type=typeof(Section))]
    public List<Widget> subsection { get; } = new List<Widget>();
}
```

`Section` is the interesting one as it defines the types permitted as child elements with the relevant name mappings. Similarly to this, you'd then define the root element:

```
[XmlRoot("dform")]
public class DForm
{
    [XmlElement("textmemo", Type=typeof(Textmemo))]
    [XmlElement("label", Type=typeof(Label))]
    [XmlElement("section", Type=typeof(Section))]
    public List<Widget> Widgets { get; } = new List<Widget>();
}
```

You can see in [this demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o0dilD) that your XML round-tripped through the serializer is the same, thus proving this works.

Comment: The reason why I was implementing IXmlSerializable is because I was using an Interface (IWidget) and the serialization process doesn't work with interfaces, unless you manage it by yourself. Of course turning  the interface into an abstract class solve the problem, as you have perfectly shown with your code, but still, for a pure exercise in style, I'd like to know how to implement the method ReadXml. In the meantime I accept your solution because this is the most efficient way to accomplish the task and it could help other developers. Many thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Below I wrote parser using Xml Linq that will work

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            new Widget(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Widget
    {
        public static Widget root = new Widget();

        public String type { get; set; }
        public String name { get; set; }
        public String labelCation { get; set; }
        public String text { get; set; }
        public String dbpath { get; set; }
        public List<Widget> subsection { get; set; }

        public Widget() { }
        public Widget(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            RecursiveParse(root, Widget.root);

        }
        public static void RecursiveParse(XElement xParent, Widget textParent)
        {
            foreach (XElement child in xParent.Elements())
            {
                string elementName = child.Name.LocalName;

                switch (elementName)
                {
                    case "label" :
                        textParent.name = (string)child.Attribute("name");
                        textParent.labelCation = (string)child.Attribute("text");
                        textParent.dbpath = (string)child.Attribute("dbpath");

                        break;
                    case "section" :
                        if (textParent.subsection == null) textParent.subsection = new List<Widget>();

                        Widget childSection = new Widget();
                        textParent.subsection.Add(childSection);
                        RecursiveParse(child, childSection);

                        break;
                    default :
                        textParent.text = (string)child.Attribute("text");
                        textParent.labelCation = elementName;
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The solution has to work with any kind of elements (textmemo, label, treecombo,..), not just with the textmemo, and I can't write a new procedure everytime I decide to add a new element to my xml. That's why I've used an interface; and since XmlSerializer doesn't work with the interfaces I have to implement my own IXmlSerializable.