# Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlserializer

I've got a very strange problem when working with .NET's `XmlSerializer`.

Take the following example classes:

```
public class Order 
{
    public PaymentCollection Payments { get; set; }

    //everything else is serializable (including other collections of non-abstract types)
}

public class PaymentCollection : Collection<Payment>
{
}

public abstract class Payment 
{
    //abstract methods
}

public class BankPayment : Payment
{
    //method implementations
}
```

AFAIK, there are three different methods to solve the `InvalidOperationException` that's caused by the serializer not knowing about the derived types of `Payment`.

**1. Adding `XmlInclude` to the `Payment` class definition:**

This is not possible due to all classes being included as external references over which I have no control of.

**2. Passing the derived types' types during creation of the `XmlSerializer` instance**

Doesn't work.

**3. Defining `XmlAttributeOverrides` for the target property in order to override the property's default serialization (as explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689566/how-to-add-xmlinclude-attribute-dynamically))**

Also doesn't work (`XmlAttributeOverrides` initialization follows).

```
Type bankPayment = typeof(BankPayment);

XmlAttributes attributes = new XmlAttributes();
attributes.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(bankPayment.Name, bankPayment));

XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof(Order), "Payments", attributes);
```

The appropriate `XmlSerializer` constructor would then be used.

NOTE: by *doesn't work* I mean the `InvalidOperationException` (*`BankPayment` was not expected...*) is thrown.

Can anyone shed some light on the subject? How would one go about and debug the issue further?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just solved the issue. After digging around for a while longer, I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616505/is-there-a-reason-why-a-base-class-decorated-with-xmlinclude-would-still-throw-a) which covers the exact same situation. It got me in the right track.

Basically, the `XmlSerializer` needs to know the default namespace **if** derived classes are included as extra types. The exact reason why this has to happen is still unknown but, still, serialization is working now.

Answer (score 113):

This worked for me:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(BankPayment))]
[Serializable]
public abstract class Payment { }    

[Serializable]
public class BankPayment : Payment {} 

[Serializable]
public class Payments : List<Payment>{}

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Payments), new Type[]{typeof(Payment)});
```

Comment: So the base type needs to know all of its implementations? This doesn't seem like a very good solution. Is there no other way?

Comment: @AlexanderStolz for generic implementation passing new Type while creating XmlSerializable Object is best solution. As mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/a/2689660/698127

Comment: The `[Serializable]` attribute is not required though. You only need to specify what types are expected to be serialized by the name of the abstract class - with the `XmlInclude` attribute.

Comment: This adds an attribute "xsi:type=". But I was hoping to replace the name of the Xml tag entirely.

Answer (score 5):

Base on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83181d16-a048-44e5-b675-a0e8ef82f5b7/why-do-i-have-to-xmlinclude-derived-classes-in-order-to-serialize?forum=asmxandxml) I was able to solve this by changing the constructor of `XmlSerializer` I was using instead of changing the classes.

Instead of using something like this (suggested in the other answers):

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Derived))]
public class Base {}

public class Derived : Base {}

public void Serialize()
{
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(SchedulePath);
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Derived>));
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, data);
    writer.Close();
}
```

I did this:

```
public class Base {}

public class Derived : Base {}

public void Serialize()
{
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(SchedulePath);
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Derived>), new[] { typeof(Derived) });
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, data);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do it in the Base, that way any child can be Serialized, less code cleaner code.

```
public abstract class XmlBaseClass  
{
  public virtual string Serialize()
  {
    this.SerializeValidation();

    XmlSerializerNamespaces XmlNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
    XmlWriterSettings XmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
      Indent = true,
      OmitXmlDeclaration = true
    };

    StringWriter StringWriter = new StringWriter();

    XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
    XmlWriter XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(StringWriter, XmlSettings);
    Serializer.Serialize(XmlWriter, this, XmlNamespaces);
    StringWriter.Flush();
    StringWriter.Close();

    return StringWriter.ToString();

  }

  protected virtual void SerializeValidation() {}
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "MyRoot", Namespace = "MyNamespace")]
public class XmlChildClass : XmlBaseClass
{
  protected override void SerializeValidation()
  {
    //Add custom validation logic here or anything else you need to do
  }
}
```

This way you can call Serialize on the child class no matter the circumstance and still be able to do what you need to before object Serializes.

Comment: I would like to highlight the code line which is important to visualize the way we can avoid XmlInclude or other attributions: 
`XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());`

Answer (score 3):

I agree with bizl

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ParentOfTheItem))]
[Serializable]
public abstract class WarningsType{ }
```

also if you need to apply this included class to an object item you can do like that

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Warnings", typeof(WarningsType))]
public object[] Items
{
    get
    {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]` for property, its resolved for me.