# Serialize a polymorphic List with the same type name

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, xmlserializer

I have an object I'm trying to serialize into XML. Inside this object is a list of a generic type (abstract class). Each item in this list could be a different class, but all are inheriting from the abstract base class:

```
public abstract class animal
{
  public string type { get; set; }
}
public class cat:animal
{
  public string size { get; set; }
  public string furColor { get; set; }
}
public class fish:animal
{
  public string size { get; set; }
  public string scaleColor { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize the list, I want it to look like this:

```
<animal type="cat">
  <size>medium</size>
  <furColor>black</furColor>
</animal>
<animal type="fish">
  <size>small</size>
  <scaleColor>silver</scaleColor>
</animal>
```

I've tried the simple solution:

```
[XmlElement("Animal")]
public List<animal> Animals { get; set; }
```

But it throws an error because it's not expecting the object type "cat." Adding the [XmlInclude] tag to either the base class, the derived class, or the whole containing class (let's call it zoo) does not help this.

I can use the typeof designation for a single class:

```
[XmlElement("Animal", typeof(cat))]
public List<animal> Animals { get; set; }
```

and this works properly, as I want it to, as long as I only use cats. Again, the minute I add a fish to the mix, it blows up with the same error (not expecting fish).

I can add multiple typeof attributes:

```
[XmlElement("Animal")]
[XmlElementAttribute(typeof(cat))]
[XmlElementAttribute(typeof(fish))]
public List<animal> Animals { get; set; }
```

and this compiles, but ignores the element name, and serializes the objects as `<cat> </cat>` and `<fish> </fish>`, respectively, which is unacceptable.

I've even tried adding multiple [XmlElement] tags:

```
[XmlElement("Animal", typeof(cat))]
[XmlElement("Animal", typeof(fish))]
public List<animal> Animals { get; set; }
```

This one throws a different exception, this time that the objects "cat" and "fish" both use the type "Animal" in the same scope.

Can anyone think of a way around this?

*UPDATE* After a little more digging, I found [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616505/is-there-a-reason-why-a-base-class-decorated-with-xmlinclude-would-still-throw-a) which suggests adding the namespace to the base class:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="myNamespace")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(cat))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(fish))]
public abstract class animal
```

Serializing this yields the following:

```
<animal xsi:type="cat" type="cat">
  ...
</animal>
<animal xsi:type="fish" type="fish">
  ...
</animal>
```

Where **xsi:type="cat"** refers to the name of the class, and **type="cat"** refers to the type attribute created within the base class (see the very top example). This is *so close* to what I need, and I fear I may just be suffering from inexperience here, but is there a way to get rid of the xsi:type attribute listing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, I missed that bit in the guidelines. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Found a partial solution, see the update at the bottom for details

Comment: Note that I also tried using `[XmlType]` in place of `[XmlRoot]` with identical results. Are there any other tags you can put on a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the XmlInclude Attribute to your base class should  solve this serilazation issue

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(cat))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(fish))]
    class animals
    {
         ....
    }

    public class cat:animals
    {
      public string size { get; set; }
      public string furColor { get; set; }
    }

    public class fish:animals
    {
      public string size { get; set; }
      public string scaleColor { get; set; }
    }
```

UPDATE

Here's a brief example that works on my side, you don't actually need the type attribute to my opinion because you can retrieve it with typeof() method. unless the type attribute had another purpose.

```
        List<animal> animals = new List<animal>();
        cat catofdoom = new cat();
        catofdoom.furColor = "brown";
        catofdoom.size = "10 pounds";
        animals.Add(catofdoom);

        fish fishofdoom = new fish();
        fishofdoom.scaleColor = "blue";
        fishofdoom.size = "12 inches";
        animals.Add(fishofdoom);


        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<animal>));
            using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("animal.xml"))
            {
                xs.Serialize(wr, animals);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

results into this ( very basic serialization with no options ) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfAnimal xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <animal xsi:type="cat">
    <size>10 pounds</size>
    <furColor>brown</furColor>
  </animal>
  <animal xsi:type="fish">
    <size>12 inches</size>
    <scaleColor>blue</scaleColor>
  </animal>
</ArrayOfAnimal>
```

Comment: I tried that, And it still gives me the error "The type cat was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically." It's entered exactly as above. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I should mention I'm using a .NET 4.5 WebAPI solution. I agree Legrandviking, the above solution _should_ work. Are we both doing something wrong? I'm hesitant to wave the "bug" flag, has anyone managed to make something like this work?

Comment: I've updated my original answer. Hopefully this will suit your need

Comment: I was able to get to that point as well when I was experimenting. unfortunately that doesn't work for what I need, either, because I'm not just serializing the list of animals, that list is embedded deep inside another object which is being serialized.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the correct answer. As I mentioned above in my update, I was finally able to make this work correctly by including the namespace before the [XmlInclude] tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need both!

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(cat))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(fish))]
class animals
{
     ....
}

public class cat:animals
{
  public string size { get; set; }
  public string furColor { get; set; }
}

public class fish:animals
{
  public string size { get; set; }
  public string scaleColor { get; set; }
}
```

Note the slight change to the `XmlElement` name. This will work correctly now.

```
[XmlElement("cat", typeof(cat))]
[XmlElement("fish", typeof(fish))]
public List<animal> Animals { get; set; }
```

Comment: This actually answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344259.aspx) and include the known types into the serializer. Using XmlInclude is kind of a break for [encasulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) principle.
See the provided MSDN link for some samples...

Comment: I agree with Jaster, much more flexible and does not require every serilizable member to be public

Comment: Hmm... This will pretty much require a refactor of the entire object... Here we go! I'll let you know in a day or two if it works :)

Comment: Okay, if my research is correct, I can't use the DataContractSerializer, because I need to be able to use attributes, so I'm stuck with XMLSerializer. Which brings me back to getting rid of some of the extraneous attributes.