# Cannot serialize interface System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

What does this mean? google search turns up nothing.

The curious thing is that I get this message when I try to access the web service directly in the browser http://localhost/Myservice/Service.asmx

But when I use the service (I invoke it inside my Jquery code) it works perfectly. Very curious detail....

Answer (score 2):

This might be because you have a function in your web service that returns  an interface, or that returns an object that contains a property or function using an interface. For further details on interfaces and serialization take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333864/xml-serialization-of-interface-property).
When you use your web service from javascript you only call one or more specific functions, but browsing on your web service with internet explorer forces a request of a whole wsdl description of your the web service with all its functions. I guess that is why it worked for the first case and not for the second.