# Dependencies & Xml Serialization

Tags: c#, architecture, xml-serialization, dependencies

In a personal application i work on at the moment i have global application settings which should affect how certain objects behave, in terms of architecture i figured it would create an unnecessary dependency to directly reference them, e.g.

```
public void Update()
{
    if (App.Settings.AutoCacheImages) CacheImages();
    ...
]
```

So i would prefer to create an interface like this:

```
public interface IFeedSettings
{
    bool AutoCacheImages { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And make sure that my object gets a reference during construction:

```
private IFeedSettings _settings;

public Feed(IFeedSettings settings)
{
    _settings = settings;
}
```

Now the problem is that Xml-Serialization requires a parameterless constructor, so what would the best way to approach this so that after deserialization all instances of `Feed` will have a reference to my global settings?

(*I have a hierarchical folder/file-like data-structure using the composite pattern*)

Comment: Have you considering making specific models for serialization, and then using something like AutoMapper to map from your entity to your model?

Comment: @Tejs: I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on that since i have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: What object is the subject of Xml Serialization?  The settings or the Feed?

Comment: @qes: The Feed. (The settings get serialized as well but they do not have any dependencies and it is just one instance so restoring them would not be a hassle if there were any)

Comment: You might get some troubles deserializing that interface: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333864/xml-serialization-of-interface-property

Comment: @ngm: No, the settings reference inside the Feed is *not supposed to be serialized*, and it *will not be serialized* because it is a private field, i do not want to have the same settings saved with every single feed, that would be horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification:

You have your object of type `Feed`. You want to serialize that, but you can't with a non default constructor. Instead, you can create a `FeedModel`, with a parameter less constructor and public properties for all the data you want to send. Then, you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to quickly transfer data from your instance of `Feed` to an instance of `FeedModel` and serialize the model class.