# Serialize Poco to XML and deserialize back to Poco (on other unrelated system)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I've got two (different) C# systems which communicate by XML. We have agreed on an XML format.

The next thing I want to do is serialize a class:

```
  public class Parent
  {
    public IChild Child { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
  public interface IChild
  {
    string Name { get; set; }
  }
  public class Girl:IChild
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FavDoll { get; set; }
  }
  public class Boy : IChild
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FavCar { get; set; }
  }
```

Result when using IXmlSerializer:

<strike>When using IXmlSerializable I get a exception there is no constructor on the Interface IChild (wellwaddayaknow).</strike>

> Ok, fixed that (thanks @Giedrius)
>
> And less ns thanks to @RobertH

[ref](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/bac96f79-82cd-4fef-a748-2a85370a8510)

```
<Parent>
  <Child>
    <Boy>
      <Name>Bill</Name>
      <FavCar>Chevvy</FavCar>
    </Boy>
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

When using DataContract I get a xmlns has a reference to the namespace. Which isn't present on the other system. So when deserializing I get a exception the reference isn't there.

```
<Parent xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Child xmlns:d2p1="TestConsole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" i:type="d2p1:TestConsole.Boy">
    <FavCar xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestConsole">Chevvy</FavCar>
    <Name xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestConsole">Bill</Name>
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

Is my only option to use XDocument and generate a lot of loc's?

Comment: You can instruct the serializer to generate the XML without the namespace, if that helps...

Comment: Not sure, can I instruct the deserializer to understand that xml and turn it into poco's?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333864/xml-serialization-of-interface-property

Comment: @rdkleine I don't know. You could try and let us/me know.

Comment: Will do. Can you give a hint on how to 'instruct the serializer to generate the XML w/o the namespace'?

Comment: @Giedrius yes, have seen some posts on 'hiding' the properties for the serializer. It seems like a solution but it would seriously mutilate my code and would rather look for other option.

Comment: @rdkleine - there offered other methods too, not only hiding, like injecting object instances during datacontract serialization.

Comment: btw, have you thought to use json instead of xml? it is more compact and it may have baked in solution for this.

Comment: @rdkleine I use the following to omit namespaces: `var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");`

Comment: @Giedrius You are right, didn't pay good enough attention. Fixed the interface issue. Now trying to get the result through deserializing.

Comment: @rdkleine to supress NS, all you need to do is: `[DataContract(Namespace="")]` if using the `DataContracSerializer`

Comment: @Giedrius your comment (similar question) worked for me, want the credits add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333864/xml-serialization-of-interface-property) there are several ways to solve interface properties issue:

- Hide interface property and deal with it in another property
- Implement IXmlSerializable
- Modify your property to use a wrapping type
- Using reflection with the DataContractSerializer to add interface property current value type to known types

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Parent
{
    [XmlElement(Type = typeof(Girl))]
    [XmlElement(Type = typeof(Boy))]
    public IChild Child { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tried your answer but getting "*Cannot serialize member TestConsole.Parent.Child of type TestConsole.IChild because it is an interface.*"