# Serialization error: there was an error reflecting type

Tags: c#, serialization

I have two classes: `ServiceTrigger` and `ServiceCalendar`.

When I serialize `model.Triggers` I am getting an exception saying:

> Cannot serialize member 'yyy.ServiceTrigger.ServiceDaysOfWeek' of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[yyyy.ServiceCalendar, yyy.ChangeAD, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]',
>       see inner exception for more details."}

I have created an `IEnumerable<ServiceTrigger>`:

```
IEnumerable<ServiceTrigger> serviceTriggers = model.Triggers;
XDocument xDoc = SerializationUtil.Serialize(model.Triggers);
```

First Class is like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceTrigger
{   
    [DataMember(Name = "triggerID")]
    public long TriggerID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dateStart")]
    public string DateStart { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "isActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dateFrom")]
    public string DateFrom { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dateTo")]
    public string DateTo { get; set; }  

    [DataMember(Name = "currentState")]
    public string CurrentState { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "daysOfWeek")]
    public IEnumerable<ServiceCalendar> ServiceDaysOfWeek { get; set; } 

    [DataMember(Name = "monthsOfYear")]
    public IEnumerable<ServiceCalendar> MonthsOfYear { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "daysOfMonth")]
    public IEnumerable<ServiceCalendar> DaysOfMonth { get; set; } 
}
```

Second Class is like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Calendar
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "isActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
)
```

My serialization class is like this:

```
public static class SerializationUtil
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(XDocument doc)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var reader = doc.Root.CreateReader())
        {
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public static XDocument Serialize(this object obj)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }

        return doc;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to fix the formatting of your post. Comments like "My serialization class is like this" should not be in a code block, makes it hard to read. Where exactly are you getting the exception? Can you please post the FULL exception?

Comment: Cannot serialize member 'yyy.ServiceTrigger.ServiceDaysOfWeek' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[yyyy.ServiceCalendar, yyy.ChangeAD, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner exception for more details."}

Comment: Cannot serialize member yyy.ServiceTrigger.ServiceDaysOfWeek of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[yyy.ServiceCalendar, yyy, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface."

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333864/xml-serialization-of-interface-property

Comment: The exception tells you "See inner exception", so you need to look at the inner exception. Please add the message of the inner exception to your question as well.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot serialize interfaces. You need to use actual objects, for instance `List<ServiceCalendar>`.

Also note that `ServiceCalendar` needs a default constructor *without* parameters in order for `XmlSerializer` to create it when deserializing. This is only important if you add a custom constructor with parameters. If you have no constructor at all, the default constructor is there already.

Example:

```
public class ServiceCalendar {
    // this is required for deserialization if a .ctor with parameters is present.
    public ServiceCalendar() { }

    public ServiceCalendar(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you will get an exception similar to

> No parameterless constructor defined for type of *ServiceCalendar*