# How to serialize n-depth ICollection constructs

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, serialization, entity-framework-6

Imagine, if you will, a data construct that looks like this:

```
public class FolderThing
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FolderThing> folders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FileThing> files { get; set; }
}

public class FileThing
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string filesize { get; set; }
}
```

This is strictly provided as an example, and has little to do with my target structure, but it serves to illustrate the problem using a metaphor we should all be familiar with.  Yes, I know, backing stores.

The structure is set up to be persisted using Entity Framework (EF6, specifically).  As you can see, **the depth of the structure is arbitrary**, in that a `FolderThing` can contain multiples of itself, *ad infinitum*.  I also want to be able to export a single `FolderThing` and all its children as an XML file that looks something like this:

```
<folderthing id="123456">
    <files>
        <filething id="456" filename="foo" filesize="125987">
        <filething id="457" filename="bar" filesize="125900">
        <filething id="458" filename="foobar" filesize="126987">
    </files>
    <folders>
        <folderthing id="123">
            <folderthing id="124">
                <files>
                    <filething id="466" filename="oof" filesize="125987">
                </files>
            </folderthing>
        </folderthing>
    </folders>
</folderthing>
```

Some time ago, [I asked how to serialize an `ICollection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016054/xml-serializing-icollection?noredirect=1#comment46276802_29016054), and that answer led me to use the `DataContractSerializer`.  Then I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902500/datacontractserializer-with-multi-tiered-data-structures/29952317?noredirect=1#comment48084713_29952317), and received a helpful answer that only ran me into the problem I'm presenting here.  So, how do I fully serialize a data structure that uses `ICollections` heavily to create an arbitrary-depth object?

Comment: Does your graph have any cycles?  Is any object the child of more than one other object?

Comment: How is this question related to EF?  What you do with this once you serialize it doesn't really affect how you go about serializing it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the first question, however the answer to the second is "not usually, though sometimes", if that's at all helpful.  At some level of depth, it's possible for an object to run into itself, which I'll have to be mindful of, putting in a trap to stop digging at that point.

Comment: It's only related to EF in that the structure is set up that way so that EF works.  If the answer includes "don't use an `ICollection`, then its not useful.

Comment: Then you do have cycles, and that makes it quite a lot more complex to serialize.  You won't be able to structure it as a tree as you have in your example.  You'll probably need to serialize it all using custom code; I wouldn't expect any built in serializer to have support for cyclical models.

Comment: How about if the object I'm serializing is exactly as the example shows?

Comment: That would make it easier, yes, but as you've said neither of those restrictions actually applies, and building a tool that *does* support them would involve a radically different approach, such an answer wouldn't actually help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76727/discussion-between-j-d-ray-and-servy).