# How to serialize Process List in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

This should be trivial: here is my attempt at the code to list running processes and serialize them to a file as list of processes:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Process> processlist = Process.GetProcesses().AsEnumerable();

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(processlist.GetType());

        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\temp\ProcessList.xml");
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(file, xmlSerializer);
        file.Close();

    }




{"Cannot serialize member 'System.ComponentModel.Component.Site' of type 'System.ComponentModel.ISite', see inner exception for more details."}
```

I have also tried serialising individual processes, with following code :

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Process> processlist = Process.GetProcesses().AsEnumerable();

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Process));

        foreach (Process process in processlist)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter( string.Format( @"D:\temp\Process{0}.xml" , process.Id));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(file, xmlSerializer);
            file.Close();   
        }
    }
```

Errors:

```
{"There was an error reflecting type 'System.Diagnostics.Process'."}


{"Cannot serialize member 'System.ComponentModel.Component.Site' of type 'System.ComponentModel.ISite', see inner exception for more details."}
```

Comment: And what is the inner exception and what does it says? The message is pretty clear that there's an inner exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9306746/762580

Comment: @artplastika, thank you that is what I can start from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializing a `Process` doesn't make sense. Imagine serializing your processes to xml and then deserializing them on another computer. How would you recreate a `Process` instance?

Maybe you're "serializing" for **logging purposes**? If that's the case, have you considered directly writing out just the process names (and all properties you care about) to xml.

```
XElement processes = new XElement("ProcessList");
foreach(var process in Process.GetProcesses().AsEnumerable())
{
    processes.Add(new XElement("Process", process.ProcessName));
}

var xmlProcessList = processes.ToString();
```

`xmlProcessList` will look something like this:

```
<ProcessList>
  <Process>devenv</Process>
  <Process>iexplore</Process>
  <Process>chrome</Process>
  ...
</ProcessList>
```

Comment: +1 , Intresting point about serialization, yes you are right deserializing them does not make sense. I was after getting all the public values of the Process Properties and it's subobjects. Yes this was for logging purposes, and I wanted to have all the public properties captured in Xml. What is the alternative to logging specific properties? I want to grab all the public properties and their values and turn them into XML. I guess I look into reflection for that.

Comment: @Arjang, you can use reflection to get all your properties. If you need only public ones, there are `BindingFlags` for that. `typeof(Process).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)` will give you a list of public properties for `Process` class