# How do I access and use generic type parameters as a regular type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

I have a generic business object collection class which contains some business objects:

```
public abstract class BusinessObjectCollection<T> : ICollection<T> 
    where T : BusinessObject
```

I want to write a method on my Collection class that returns the type T and a method that returns a newly-instantiated object of type T.

In C++, this would be where you simply declare a `typedef value_type T;` and use BusinessObjectCollection::value_type but I can't find an equivalent in C#.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: One close parallel to the typedef I was thinking of is the method:

```
Type GetGenericParameter() { 
    return typeof(T); 
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public abstract class BusinessObjectCollection<T> : ICollection<T> 
    where T : BusinessObject, new()
{
    // Here is a method that returns an instance
    // of type "T"
    public T GetT()
    {
        // And as long as you have the "new()" constraint above
        // the compiler will allow you to create instances of
        // "T" like this
        return new T();
    }
}
```

In C# you can use the type parameter (i.e. `T`) as you would any other type in your code - there is nothing extra you need to do.

In order to be able to create instances of `T` (without using reflection) you must constrain the type parameter with `new()` which will guarantee that any type arguments contain a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Actually this does use reflection too. C# emits a call to Activator.CreateInstance.

Comment: That is very true that the *compiler* emits calls to `Activator.CreateInstance`.  I was simply stating that the OP would not have to use the reflection API directly, not that reflection was not used at all under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to finding a type:

If you need to know what the type of T is, [you can simply use `typeof(T)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t).