# how to remove IEnemurable in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<StudentInfo>>" %>
```

in my view if i have IEnumerable I can do foreach..

but before that i need to access the properties for StudnetInfo..

StudentInfo clas having

```
Public class StudentInfo
{
  public Studentdetails sd {get;set;}
  public classDetails  cd {get;set;}
}

<% foreach(var e in Model){%>
<div>
 <%=Html.DisplayFor(x=>e.StdentEdit) %>
    <div>
    <span>
     <% Html.RenderAction("Details", "Home", new { @t = e }); %>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<% } %>
```

please can anybody help me out.. how to get the properties of StudentInfo above the foreach loop...

if i remove IEnemurable I can do that.. but i need to have Ienemurable for RenderAction..

is there any other way we can achieve this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e will be of type StudentInfo, call:

```
e.GetType().GetProperties()
```

If you need to grab the generic argument type from your Model directly without iterating I recommend this existing SO question:

[How to get the type of T from a member of a generic class or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

(2nd answer should work for you)

Comment: do I need to keep before foreach loop? but i can not e there?
how to access the properties only once above the foreach loop?
thanks

Comment: I linked to the question explaining how to do it before the foreach loop.