# Can I get the item type from a BindingSource?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, bindingsource

I would like to get the Type of item that a BindingSource is hooked up to or configured for.  The BindingSource.DataSource property can be set to an object, list, or type.  If it is a Type, it obviously does not have a bound item yet, but I would still like to get the Type.  For a List, I need the item Type, not the list type.

I currently have a custom list type for business objects that implement an IListItemType interface, that I created to solve this problem a while back.  I would now like to get this working in a more generic fashion so that it will work with any list.

I've looked through the API docs for for a good way to do this, but so far I have not had any luck.  Am I missing something or is this just something I can not or should not be doing?

Comment: Check out this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t

Comment: @Mikael: That question doesn't seem to be related; this question sounds like it's dealing with the list *outside* of the class, not *inside*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently ran across the **ListBindingHelper** class in the framework that has everything I was looking for:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetListItemType()
```

> Returns the type of an item contained in a list or collection.

```
ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties()
```

> Returns a PropertyDescriptorCollection that describes the properties of the items contained in the list.

Answer (score 2):

There is no completely generic way to get the "type" of the list. The most common method is to examine the first item, but this can be misleading as you can have objects that are of a *more specific* type in a collection that is *less specific* (in other words, the collection might be a `List<object>`, but the first item might be a `string`, leading you to guess that it's a `List<string>`). If you're confident that all of the elements will be the same type (meaning none are more specific than the generic type of the collection or than any of the other objects), then examining the first item is the easiest.

Apart from that, you could examine the list's actual type using `GetType` and check its interfaces. Chances are that *any* collection that's strongly typed is going to implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can iterate over its interfaces looking for `IEnumerable` that's generic, then look at its generic type arguments. It's (more than) a little hokey, but it should work.

**TL;DR Version**

Try this. Assuming you're using .NET 3.5 and have the list stored in a variable called `list`:

```
var listType = list.GetType().GetInterfaces()
              .Where(t => t.Name == "IEnumerable" && t.IsGenericType)
              .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0]).FirstOrDefault();
```

As long as the list implements `IEnumerable<T>`, this will give you `T`. If it doesn't, chances are the list type is `object` anyway.

Comment: After looking into this, the GetItemProperties method looks like it is not going to be much help.  You have to pass in a list of properties and then it will return the ones that exist on the item.  So this gets me back to the issue of how do I get the item type to get the list of properties.  I will edit the question to remove the incorrect speculation on that point.

Comment: There is enough to think about here that I am pretty sure there is not going to be way to get the item type directly from the BindingSource as I had hoped.  I think I just need to limit my scope and assume that the BindingSource is going to have a generic list type or a type derived from a generic list type set as the DataSource and just move on from there... or a directly bound single item.  Anyway you get the idea, de-scope the edge cases and the problem goes away.  Thanks for you thoughts.

Comment: @Preston: Yeah, unfortunately there's no completely generic way to do it. I do think, though that if you assume that: 1) Any list (collection, not necessarily `List<T>`) that's strongly typed will implement `IEnumerable<T>` for the desired type T, and 2) Any non-strongly typed list will implement `IEnumerable` and have desired type of `object`, and 3) Anything else is a single-bound object, then you'll cover 99% of the possibilities.

Comment: I think it has to be "t.Name.Contains("IEnumerable")".

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite a while since this answer has been on board but just in case anybody is still looking for the answer...

I ran into a similar problem. My scenario was that BindingSource.DataSource would always be bound to an IEnumerable BUT there may not be any items in the list. It turns out that BindingSource has a private instance member called "itemType". This field does just what you're looking for: it shows the element type of a list if the BindingSource is bound to a list, or it shows the type of the object that the BindingSource is bound to, if there is no list.

To access the field value, I used some hacky reflection:

```
FieldInfo fi = 
    typeof(BindingSource)
    .GetField("itemType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
Type myElementType = fi.GetValue(DataBinder.RestrictedDataBinding) as Type;
```

Without doing much research, I kind of assume that what it's doing is showing the element type of the innerList, which is why it doesn't matter if the DataSource is a list type or not. Also, I assume this field would accurately show the element type of any kind of list that is supported by the BindingSource (including IQueryables, etc.).

WARNING: I have NOT tested this field much so I don't know if there are cases that would make it not read the correct element type. For example, does the field always get accurately updated when the BindingSource's DataSource property is reset? What if the DataSource property is reset to a list that has a different elementType? In my case, these exceptions and others don't apply but you might want to test them.

Lastly, using reflection to hack into private fields breaks all kinds of oop principles. Keep that in mind. Also, keep in mind that there very well might be a good reason why the itemType field was hidden. If you need to investigate further, the code for the BindingSource class is publicly available.