# Get actual type of T in a generic List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

How do I get the actual type of T in a generic List at run time using reflection?

Comment: What does your current code look like? A bit of context would help

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# generic list <T> how to get the type of T?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you’re asking:

- **While writing code inside a generic type `Blah<T>`, how do I get the reflection type `T`?**

  Answer: `typeof(T)`
- **I have an object which contains a `List<T>` for some type `T`. How do I retrieve the type `T` via reflection?**

  Short answer: `myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]`

  Long answer:

  ```
  var objectType = myList.GetType();
  if (!objectType.IsGenericType() ||
      objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(List<>))
  {
      throw new InvalidOperationException(
          "Object is not of type List<T> for any T");
  }
  var elementType = objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
  ```

Comment: BTW - This will throw on GetGenericTypeDefinition() if "myList" is not a generic type... If you're going to put in the error checking, you should include a check for IsGenericType, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Type.GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) to return the type T in a `List<T>`.

For example, this will return the Type for any `List<T>` passed as an argument:

```
Type GetListType(object list)
{
    Type type = list.GetType();
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("list is not a List<T>", "list");
}
```

Comment: Not really useful: You can only pass an object in there for which you already know the type at compile-time.

Comment: @Timwi - I can think of a dozen places this is useful, just because you have a `T` at compile time, doesn't mean you know it (generic constraints for example).  There there are a few ways to go about it, e.g. `ElementType` on an `IQueryable<T>`, but don't dismiss this as not useful.

Comment: @Timwi: Although I put this just as a very simple usage scenario - it works fully from reflection, as well.  The GetGenericArguments call is the main way, via reflection, to pull this out.  Granted, in this case, I could just have returned typeof(T) and been done with it - but I don't know how the OP is getting the "List<T>" in the first place... That being said, doing reflection on generic arguments in a generic method like this can be useful in some situations...

Comment: @Nick, @Reed: Can you provide some example code (e.g. via pastebin.com) where it would actually be useful? The way I see it, wherever you write `GetGenericType(list)`, the type of `list` must at compile-time be `List<X>` with `X` known at compile-time, so no matter what `X` is, you can just as easily write `typeof(X)` instead.

Comment: @Timwi: Does that make you happier?  Now it's getting the full type via reflection... including the proper checks to see if it's a List<T> via IsGenericType + the TypeDefinition check...

Comment: Yes, now your answer is pretty much identical to mine ☺

Comment: @Timwi: Except for the extra comment I added on yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof (T)
```

or

```
typeof (T).UnderlyingSystemType
```

Answer (score 0):

New solution old problem by `dynamic`

```
void Foo(){
   Type type GetTypeT(data as dynamic);
}

private static Type GetTypeT<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```