# Get the Type of T of the generic List<T> object

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reflection - Getting the generic parameters from a System.Type instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293905/reflection-getting-the-generic-parameters-from-a-system-type-instance)
>   [Get actual type of T in a generic List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689308/get-actual-type-of-t-in-a-generic-listt)

I'm looping through a PropertyInfo-List from a Class.
In this class, I'm interested in the different Lists - for example `List<int>`, `List<string>`, `List<Book>`, aso.

But I don't know how I get the Type of the List-Objects. I just get something like

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].
```

I could take this information apart and create a Type out of this information, but I hope there's a smoother way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple:

```
Type type = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
// The first argument will be the `T` inside `List<T>`... so the list type ;)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var  list = GetListFromFoo();
Type listType = list.GetType();
Type theTypeOfT = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Or with one line:

```
list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```