# Is there a way to get the type of the objects stored in a generic list?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, gettype

Given a generic list of type `List<T>` how do I find type `T`?

I suppose if the list is populated I could take `listInstance[0].GetType()` but that seems a bit hackish.

**Edit:**

For context, I want to populate a DataTable with columns based on the Properties of an object. Where an object property is a generic list I want to add a column for each property of the object stored by the list. I'll flatten the data structure to fit into a DataRow later.

The reason I don't want to use the type of the first object in the list is because it's not guaranteed that every instance will have the list populated. Some will and some won't, but I'll still need all the columns ahead of time.

Comment: Yes, it is, at least in your case. If you are using generic collection, you shouldn't mix typecasting it to Array eigther object or object[] and vice versa. Just keep using typed versions. T.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the type of T from a generic List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-generic-listt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```
typeof(List<T>).GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

This works with an empty array, while your version does not.

UPDATE:

On an instance use

```
instance.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

Comment: Not stupid, but easy ;). I'm supriesed how many people would risk a IndexOutOfRangeException on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Why is that hackish?, is not hackish at all. That is why the `GetType()` method exits. To obtain the type of the object.

Comment: I disagree. What if the list is empty?

Comment: @Phil He explicitly said "suppose list is populated"

Comment: @Liviu, yes I know because I wrote the original post.

Comment: @Klaus, how does that help me find the type of the first object in the list?

Comment: @Klaus, we seem to be at cross purposes - I really don't understand what your point is.

Comment: And now it looks like I'm talking to an imaginary friend.

Answer (score 1):

It is hackish because if the list isn't populated, you can't get an answer.

You'll need to reflect against the Type:

```
List<int> mylist = new List<int>();
Type listType = mylist.GetType();
Type genericType = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Comment: You can just indent each line of a code block by 4 spaces (or highlight it and click the toolbar button). You don't have to use that `<code>/<br>` nonsense here on SO. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()
```

This returns an array of all the types specified in the declaration of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Do it as you said. It is not hackish.

You can also call GetType() directly on your list and use it to look at type of its its T.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do `listInstance[0] is SomeTypeIExpectThisToBe` if you are expecting a type and want to do something because of that

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to the type parameter, so you can use typeof:

```
void ProcessList<T>( List<T> listInstance)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
}
```