# Get the Type of a generic Interface?

Tags: c#, generics

I got a generic Interface like this :

```
public interface IResourceDataType<T>
{
    void SetResourceValue(T resValue);
}
```

Then I got this class that implements my Interface :

```
public class MyFont : IResourceDataType<System.Drawing.Font>
{
    //Ctor + SetResourceValue + ...
}
```

And finally I got a :

```
var MyType = typeof(MyFont);
```

I, now, want to get the `System.Drawing.Font` Type from MyType !
At the moment, I got this code :

```
if (typeof(IResourceDataType).IsAssignableFrom(MyType))
{
    //If test is OK
}
```

But I don't manage to "extract" my Type here...
I tried a couple of things with `GetGenericArguments()` and other things but they either don't compile or return a null value/List...
What do I have to do ?

EDIT :
Here is the solution that fit my code for those who will get the same problem :

```
if (typeof(IResourceDataType).IsAssignableFrom(MyType))
{
    foreach (Type type in MyType.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType)
            Type genericType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t

Comment: Yep, and a couple of another ones, they don't answer to my question... My feeling is that I have to use GetInterfaces() and do some other things, I'm actually trying it !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since your `MyFont` class only implements one interface, you can write:

```
Type myType = typeof(MyFont).GetInterfaces()[0].GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

If your class implements several interfaces, you can call the [GetInterface()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayfa0fcd.aspx) method with the mangled name of the interface you're looking for:

```
Type myType = typeof(MyFont).GetInterface("IResourceDataType`1")
                            .GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying, but I do implement multi-interfaces, that was just a snippet to expose my problem !

Comment: I'll "EDIT" with the final solution, I'm close to it

Comment: You'll have to use `GetInterface()` then, see my updated answer.

Comment: Used "IsGeneric", see the Solution is my question :) thanks for ur help anyway !

Comment: In fact your solution is the good one Frederic, but is there a way to get something more robust than just a string ? I mean, if I rename my Interface, the compiler won't say anything with your code :/

Comment: I don't know if it really qualifies as *more robust*, but [FindInterfaces()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.findinterfaces.aspx) takes a filter delegate and a criteria argument instead of a string, so you can implement the search algorithm yourself is you wish to do so.

Answer (score 6):

```
var fontTypeParam = typeof(MyFont).GetInterfaces()
    .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
    .Where(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IResourceDataType<>))
    .Select(i => i.GetGenericArguments().First())
    .First()
    ;
```

This takes care of you concern about renaming the interface.  There's no string literal, so a rename in Visual Studio should update your search expression.