# Get type and cast second variable to that type

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# generic list <T> how to get the type of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

I have a list variable and I want to get the type of that list and cast a second variable to that type. For clarity I added the code below.

Currently I have the following:

```
return _ValueList.Any<FieldType>(x => x.Equals((FieldType)fieldValueObject));
```

I want to do something like this:

```
Type valueType = _ValueList.GetType();

return _ValueList.Any<FieldType>(x => x.Equals((valueType)fieldValueObject));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Update:

A invalid cast exception is thrown when fieldValueObject is of type Int16 and I try to cast it to Int32.

Update 2:

I used the following solution:

```
        if (fieldValueObject.GetType() == typeof(Int16))
        {
            fieldValueObject = Convert.ToInt32(fieldValueObject);
        }
        return _ValueList.Any<FieldType>(x => x.Equals(fieldValueObject));
```

It is not pretty but it works.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish ? Are you trying to filter a List of numbers with a string value ? Seeing the rest of the function would help.

Comment: I am trying to check if a value exist in a generic list. The value that I am testing for is retrieved from a db, and when I to cast it to the list type it throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public bool ContainsAny<T>(List<T> valueList, T fieldValueObject)
{
    return valueList.Any(x => x.Equals(fieldValueObject));
}
```

or

```
public bool ContainsAny<T>(List<T> valueList, object fieldValueObject)
{
    return valueList.Any(x => x.Equals((T)fieldValueObject));
}
```

**Note that the second can throw an InvalidCastException.**

Comment: Both these methods works fine, except when fieldValueObject is of type Int16 and I try to cast it to Int32.

Comment: @FreddieGericke If you absolutely must do a cast, consider using type converters. `(T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFrom(fieldValueObject);`