# System.Type from <T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

How can i get the System.Type of a  (Type in a generic function)?
I need to get a string representation of the class name.

```
typeof(T).GetType().Name
```

gives me 'runtimetype', which i do not want.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
typeof(T)
```

That will result in the actual type of `T` whatever `T` is for that particular instance of your generic class/method.  If `T` happened to be `System.String`, you would get an instance of the type representing `System.String`.

Comment: Elaborating so you understand what is happening: `typeof(T)` is a `System.Type` that describes `T`. Therefore, `typeof(T).GetType()` is a `System.Type` that describes `System.Type`. The name is therefore `System.Type`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use like this ?

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();   // Get your current class type
thisType.FullName                 // Get your Assembly Name.
```

**Edit**
    in you class,

```
Type thistype = TypeOf(T);
thisType.Name                    // Get you class name
```

Comment: No i can not. My function looks something like this:

public static T DoSomething<T>() {
    string className = ???;
    DoSomethingWithClassName();
}

Comment: `TypeOf` does not exist in C#, it is the [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(v=vs.110).aspx) operator.