# Generically apply a generic TypeConverter to an existing generic type

Tags: .net, generics, reflection, f#

I wrote a generic type converter with the following type signature -

```
type AlgebraicConverter<'t> () =
    inherit TypeConverter ()
    ...
```

I wish to apply this converter to an existing generic type such as Option<'t>. Also, I wish to do so generically such that Option will automatically use an AlgebraicConverter> for its converter.

Because I don't have control over the existing type's definition, I cannot specify the custom type converter in the usual way via the following declaration -

```
type [<TypeConverter (typeof<AlgebraicConverter<Option<'t>>>)>] Option<'t> = ...
```

So far, I've only been able apply my generic converter to particular type instantiations of an existing type by using the TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes method like so -

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes (typeof<Option<int>>, TypeConverterAttribute typeof<AlgebraicConverter<Option<int>>>)
```

However, this is unsatisfactory for two reasons -

1) I cannot know in advance just what different type instantiations my users will possibly need, and

2) It would be impractical to try to apply this converter to every possible instantiation anyway.

What technique(s) might I employ to *generically* apply my generic type converter to an existing generic type? Hopefully there is a satisfactorily elegant approach to achieving this.

C#'rs, please feel free to answer this question as well; only the exemplifying types used in this question are specific to F#.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The problem has to parts:

1. You want to add an extra attribute, at runtime, to any type *whatsoever* whose 
   generic definition is `option< >`. However, you can only
   go so far as to add the extra attribute to the generic `option< >` *itself*, 
   using `typedefof<int option>` instead of `typeof<int option>`. But this 
   leaves the specific `typeof<int option>`, `typeof<float option>`, etc. untouched. 
   Later, when the component model has an instance to convert, it looks for the 
   `TypeConverterAttribute` only on the instance's specific type, not on any generic 
   type it may possibly be associated with.
2. Even if a way existed to solve part 1,
   you would still have to decide on a specific AlgebraicConverter to add to the type 
   descriptor system. You can't add a generic `AlgebraicConverter< >`. However, 
   this is more of a design issue, which could be solved easily.

#### Workarounds

If you insist on using only *one* converter, you have to make the converter non-generic and map it to the Object type. However, the converter will then replace any previously defined converters. Internally, the converter branches by target subtype
(and may *then* still delegate to additional converters if you prefer this kind of design).

```
type GlobalConverter() =
    inherit TypeConverter()
    // etc.

TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(
    typeof<obj>, 
    TypeConverterAttribute typeof<GlobalConverter>)
```

On the other hand, if you want to stick to the `AlgebraicConverter<'T>`, you have to add a new instance for each specific target type.

```
let addAlgebraicConverter<'T> = 
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(
        typeof<'T>,
        TypeConverterAttribute typeof<AlgebraicConverter<'T>>) 
    |> ignore

addAlgebraicConverter<int>
addAlgebraicConverter<int option>
addAlgebraicConverter<decimal>
addAlgebraicConverter<decimal option>
```

Comment: There are no workarounds who fit your prescription (using just one instance of a generic converter), but I have edited the answer with some other workarounds.

Comment: It's starting to seem as if I need to somehow make my converter non-generic. Perhaps I should attempt to proceed in that direction?

Comment: So I attempted to proceed in that direction, but that renders AlgebraicConverter without enough type information to implement ConvertFrom, et al, EG - it has no idea the type it's actually supposed to convert to...

Comment: So I went ahead and stopped using the ConvertFrom functionality entirely, rendering the above issue moot. I had to manually circumvent my PropertyGrid's use of it, however, with a rather ugly hack. The journey continues...

Comment: My status is thus - now that I have generalized AlgebraicConverter by removing its type parameter, I can get it to work on my own types by attributing them with it. However, even with the generalization and using TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes with typedefof, I am still unable to provoke TypeDescriptor.GetConverter to return the AlgebraicConverter for existing types. Also unfortunately, I cannot assign AlgebraicConverter to all types because of the hack I had to do in ConvertFrom to make it play nice with the PropertyGrid. I seem to be at an impasse, though have made some progress, I suppose.

Comment: After further effort, I must report that it seems that this assertion of yours is not true - 'The converter will then be used for each type who does not have another converter defined yet.' After a bit of experimenting, it seems that assigning any converter to the obj type will result in that converter always coming back from TypeDescriptor.GetConverter. Do you have some evidence that my conclusion is in err?

Comment: I've also now figure out how to get enough type information to implement ConvertFrom properly and remove the PropertyGrid hack thanks to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823669/cannot-create-a-typeconverter-for-a-generic-type . Still, I cannot find a solution to applying my AlgebraicConverter to an existing generic type - unless perhaps I made it capable of converting ALL types in .NET (which is not what I want to do).

Comment: Re. "[...] using `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes` with `typedefof`, I am still unable to provoke `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter` to return the `AlgebraicConverter` for existing types": as mentioned in the answer, `typedefof` does not work. Only `typeof` works.

Comment: Re. "[...] this assertion of yours is not true - 'The converter will then be used for each type who does not have another converter defined yet.'": I have re-tested this carefully, and it turns out that indeed my assertion was not true. I have corrected the answer accordingly. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Re. "Still, I cannot find a solution to applying my AlgebraicConverter to an existing generic type - unless perhaps I made it capable of converting ALL types in .NET (which is not what I want to do)": As a last resort, you can recursively reflect on the object before it is passed to `PropertyGrid.SelectedObject`. In the recursion, deal with `option< >`, `seq< >`, and `Type.GetProperties`. It's a lot of work...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the static constructor of the Option class:

```
static Option()
{
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes (typeof<Option<T>>, TypeConverterAttribute typeof<AlgebraicConverter<Option<T>>>) 
}
```

This worked for me when I had the same problem