# Get type name of T using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have:

```
public class MyUserControl : WebUserControlBase <MyDocumentType>{...}
```

How do I get the TypeName of `MyDocumentType` if I'm in another class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
typeof(MyUserControl).BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty answers showing how to get the type of `T` if you *know* that the class derives directly from `WebUserControlBase<T>`. Here's how to do it if you want to be able to go up the hierarchy *until* you encounter the `WebUserControlBase<T>`:

```
var t = typeof(MyUserControl);
while (!t.IsGenericType
    || t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(WebUserControlBase<>))
{
    t = t.BaseType;
}
```

And then go on to get `T` by reflecting on the generic type arguments of `t`.

Since this is an example and not production code, I 'm not handling the case where `t` represents a type that does not derive from `WebUserControlBase<T>` at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .NET 4.5:

```
typeof(MyUserControl).BaseType.GenericTypeArguments.First();
```

Comment: This is good, but one should keep in mind that the `GenericTypeArguments` property only exists starting from .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Type.GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method.

> Returns an array of Type objects that represent the type arguments of
>   a generic type or the type parameters of a generic type definition.

Like

```
typeof(MyUserControl).BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

Since return type of this method is  `System.Type[]`, the array elements are returned in the order in which they appear in the list of type arguments for the generic type.