# How to access properties of an object in a list?

Tags: c#, .net, generic-list

I am trying to take properties from a list of types and put them in another list. I am not exactly sure how you iterate through the list of objects to gain access to the properties.

For example:

```
List<images> myImages = new List<images>();

List<string> typeOfImage = new List<string>();

typeOfImage.Add(myImages.type);
```

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Just Look at [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
typeOfImage = myImages.Select(image => image.AnyPropertyYouNeed).ToList();
```

Comment: Dont forget to add using System.Linq; to your usings

Comment: @Ferdy Good comment. Thanks. This is required to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myImages.Count < 0)
   typeOfImage.Add(myImage[0].GetType().ToString());
```

Comment: Or petro's solution if you want each type of image in your second list.