# How to get the Type of T in generic lists

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, generic-list

I am working on an editor that reflects my classes and converts them into UI fields to let me create objects files by changing the values of the fields in the UI and saving them.

The problem is when I use generic list, the editor builder stops because it doesn't know the type of the object in the list to reflect it, it keeps considering the object as `object`.

I just need to know what is the type of the object in the list or dictionary to reflect it.

The Code :

```
class ListUIEditor<T> : BaseEditor where T : new()
{
    void BuildEditor()
    {
       Button addbutton = new Button("+");
       addbutton.Clicked += add_Event;

        for (int i = 0; i < ((List<T>)base.boundObject).Count; i++)
        {
            container = new Container();         
            ObjectUIEditor editor = new ObjectUIEditor("itemName",
                                                       ((List<T>)base.boundObject)[i], 
                                                       container);
            editor.buildEditor();
            itemsSubEditors.Add(i, editor);
        }
    }

    protected void add_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        T newObject = new T();          
        container = new Container();            
        ObjectUIEditor editor = new ObjectUIEditor("itemName", newObject, container);
        editor.buildEditor();           
        itemsBox.ShowAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# generic list <T> how to get the type of T?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

Comment: I saw that question, but the difference is that I am not asking for the Type of T in the same class that contains it :

"your list has the same type parameter as the container class itself."

Comment: This one also returned the Type : object 
not my desired class

Comment: Try the second answer in that question (the one answered by YD1m here). If you still have problem, please post the actual code.

Comment: Please add the code you're using, your question is unclear.

Comment: @user2302005 in which line is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Type type = listObj.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

[ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx)

Comment: I tried this in two ways and both didn't work:
1:

T listObj = new T()
Type type = listObj.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

this gave an exception

2:
Type[] type = boundObject.GetType().GetGenericArguments();

This return an array with one element witch is : object

Comment: @user2302005 - If your in a generic method whose generic argument matches the generic list type, you can just use `Type itemType = typeof(T);`.

Comment: @user2302005 "2: Type[] type = boundObject.GetType().GetGenericArguments(); This return an array with one element witch is : object " -- Are you dealing with a `List<object>`? If so, if you've only got that type information, you cannot determine which types of objects it can contain, you need to look at the individual objects.

Comment: @Lee 
It returned the type : object not my desired class

Comment: @hvd 
I am dealing with List<T> because I could get a list of any type to refelect it

Comment: @user2302005 `List<T>` with `T = object` is `List<object>`... If your goal is to have `T` some other type, you need to make `T` some other type, but you haven't shown any relevant code to suggest `T` is anything.

Comment: @user2302005: Tell us what all objects share, what similarity do they have. Maybe we can suggest to create an interface or common base class. There are must be reason why you use the same collection for all.