# How to find out the type of list items and then create a list of that type of items?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to use a generic `List<T>` custom class `MyList<T>` for automated items parsing and I'm stuck at creating a return type of `MyList<T>`. Specifically I don't know how to create such a list with the given type. One thing I can do is find out the type and store it in a `Type itemType` variable.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t) helped me find out the type of list items.

The catch is I don't know the list type until runtime, so it can't be written explicitly in code.

How do I create a list of items of a certain type using a `Type itemType` variable?

Comment: Pretty unclear, can you show declaration of MyList<T> and method where you should return it? You may need to use Reflection to create an object of type MyList<T> when T is known at run-time but **you may not be able to return a typed object**. Or maybe yes...well all depends on the context...

Comment: I just tried to clarify the question with a dozen of small edits. During runtime I get the expected type of items the list should carry, and then I need to create a new instance of such list with the item type I just got.

Comment: Can't you pass `dynamic` as the list type and `Cast<T>` them at runtime later?

Comment: @aevitas this *is* being done at runtime already and both list and item types are not known before that.

Comment: @user1306322 Alright, so declare your list as `MyList<dynamic>`, get the `TypeCode` of the objects during runtime and cast them into their respective types using a switch or something similar. This is of course assuming you're only dealing with value types and not reference types.

Comment: Can you explain why this won't work `MyList<T> GetList<T>();`.

Comment: @ja72 exactly that line of code is nonsense in C# and I'm not sure what you could mean. Using the type name explicitly is not an option in this case btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Reflection, for example:

```
var listType = typeof(List<>);
listType.MakeGenericType(typeof(MyType))

return Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Another example, if all you have is an instance of "MyType" but don't know what it is until runtime:

```
public IEnumerable GetGenericListFor(object myObject){
    var listType = typeof(List<>);
    listType.MakeGenericType(myObject.GetType())
    return Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
}
```

Comment: Depending on what your trying to do, if you have an array/enumerable of objects of "MyType", you may be able to use Linq's "enumerable.ToList()" extension to turn the array into a list.

Comment: The instance seems to be of correct type, but I can't access any of `MyType`'s properties or methods. There are no methods of the `List` type even, so I can't add items to it. I think I need to cast it before that, but I don't know how, without explicitly typing the type to cast to.

Comment: In that case, instead of returning "IEnumerable", cast it to "ICollection" instead, since IList<T> implements both, you can use the Add/remove methods.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx) is the corresponding MSDN article about dynamically creating generic types given the generic type, and the parameter types. Scroll to "Constructing an Instance of a Generic Type" section around the middle.

Quick sample:

```
Type d1 = typeof(Dictionary<,>);
Type[] typeArgs = {typeof(string), typeof(int)};
Type constructed = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
```