# How to get type of T of SomeType<T1>

Tags: c#, generics, types

Having generic types like this:

```
SomeType<T>
SomeType<T1, T2>
```

and only have the type of them:

```
Type type1 = typeof(SomeType<T>);
Type type2 = typeof(SomeType<T1, T2>);
```

How to get the type of  `T` from `type1`
 and `T1` and `T2` from `type2`?

**Example:**
Using `typeof(SomeType<int>)` will only return `SomeType´1`.
But I'm searching for a way to get the `int` type, just as `typeof(int)` will do.

Comment: `Type.GetGenericArguments()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method on `Type` class, that will return specific Types, that you have used to specify open generic types. Example for your case:

```
var type = typeof(SomeType<int, string>);

foreach(Type closedType in type.GetGenericArguments())
{
    Console.WriteLine(closedType);
}
```

where

```
class SomeType<T1, T2> {}
```

will print:

```
System.Int32
System.String
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on `SomeType` but I would suggest something like this:

```
Type innerType = type1.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;
```

Comment: I guess the property `Item` means the indexer. But does this work when the `SomeType<T>` does not implement a indexer?