# How to iterate List<T> where T: MyClass

Tags: c#, list, loops

I have entity with nested list:

```
public class Article : MyEntityBase
{
    public Article()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }

    [MyAttribute]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MyAttribute]
    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag : EntityBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MyEntityBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have function that collects all `[MyAttribute]` marked properties and do something operations with them:

```
public function OperateWithAttributes(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties)
{
    foreach (var p in properties)
    {
        if (p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            // do something
        }
        else if (/* there are code that check property type is List<T> */)
        {
            /* there are code that iterate list */
        }
    }
}
```

### Questions:

- How to compare property type with `List<T>`?
- How to iterate list if I know that it's inherited from `EntityBase`?

### P.S

I'm using .NET 4.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to compare property type with `List<T>`:

```
if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
    p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
```

How to iterate list if I know that [its items are] inherited from EntityBase:

```
var listForIteration = (IEnumerable<EntityBase>)list;

foreach (var item in listForIteration)
{
}
```

A `List<T>` is not covariant, but (as of .NET 4.0) an `IEnumerable<T>` is.

**UPDATE**: After some comments, here's an answer to the question you didn't ask:

How to test if I can enumerate an object as a sequence of items that inherit from EntityBase, and if so, loop over it:

```
var listForIteration = list as IEnumerable<EntityBase>;

if (listForIteration != null)
{
    foreach (var item in listForIteration)
    {
    }
}
```

This will (on .NET 4.0 or later) allow you to iterate any collection of EntityBase (or derived) objects, even if the collection is not a `List<>` (except for those that don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but those are rare).

Comment: "but an `IEnumerable<T>` is" - Only in .NET 4. The OP is probably using .NET 4, but it's worth pointing out for others that read this.

Comment: "that it's inherited from EntityBase" should be "that its items inherit from EntityBase" probably :)

Comment: Whether or not `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant depends on the framework version; also, it *may or may not matter*, but note that this doesn't handle things like `public class MyCustomList : List<Foo>` or `public class MyEventMoreCustomList : IList<Bar>`

Comment: @BartoszKP only quoting the OP's question verbatim

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Yes I know, but obviously OP misspoken this one, so it should be corrected, for sake of strictness that we, programmers, should love and encourage ;)

Comment: @EliArbel the edge-cases I mentioned relate to your first test involving `IsGenericType` and `GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))` - where they most certainly *do not* work. The covariance issue I mentioned related to the framework version, where again: this is a problem on, say, 3.5

Comment: @MarcGravell I know, but my understanding is that those edge cases are not what the OP is asking for (OP doesn't define "compare" but I assume "test equality" is intended), so I didn't update my answer. If the question would be "how can I test if I can iterate" the answer would simple by to cast to the covariant interface using the `as` operator. (Also, I think you're confusing me with Eli Arbel.)

Answer (score 4):

> How to compare property type with `List<T>`?

Correctly identifying something as a list is ... tricky; especially if you want to handle all edge-cases (a custom `IList<Foo>` implementation, or a class that subclasses `List<T>`, etc). A lot of framework code checks instead for "implements the non-generic `IList`, and has a non-`object` indexer":

```
    static Type GetListType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null) return null;
        if (!typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(type)) return null;

        var indexer = type.GetProperty("Item", new[] { typeof(int) });
        if (indexer == null || indexer.PropertyType == typeof(object))
            return null;

        return indexer.PropertyType;
    }
```

> How to iterate list if I know that it's inherited from `EntityBase`?

Assuming you mean that the *items* are inherited from `EntityBase`, and you have determined that it is a list (from the previous question), then the easiest option is `IList` and `foreach`:

```
var itemType = GetListType(p.PropertyType);
if(itemType != null && itemType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityBase)))
{
    var list = (IList) p.GetValue(obj);
    foreach(EntityBase item in list)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note: if you are going to get the value *anyway*, you can also reverse this and use an `is` test **before** using `GetListType`:

```
var value = p.GetValue(obj);
Type itemType;
if(value is IList && (itemType = GetListType(p.PropertyType) != null)
      && itemType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityBase)))
{
    var list = (IList)value;
    foreach(EntityBase item in list)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like

```
Type type = p.PropertyType;
if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>) &&
   typeof(EntityBase).IsAssignableFrom(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
{
    // iterate list
}
```

Comment: `type.GetGenericArguments()[0] is EntityBase` is wrong, that should be something like `typeof(EntityBase).IsAssignableFrom(type.GetGenericArguments()[0])`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to iterate the list, you can use `IEnumerable<out T>`'s covariance:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable<EntityBase>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
{
    var enumerable = (IEnumerable<EntityBase>)p.GetValue(obj);
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to iterate list if I know that it's inherited from EntityBase?

You know it's a subclass of type `EntityBase`, so instead of using generics, why not just go for a good old superclass reference? Then there's no need to use generics in this scenario, when `List<EntityBase>` will do fine.

Comment: @jon That cast won't work, as `List<T>` is not covariant. Classes can't be covariant in .NET, but interfaces can. See my answer.

Comment: Cannot cast "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Tag]" to type "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EntityBase]".

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: ...which is why I commented.