# How to get Class Instance of class from Type or string form of Class name

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-conversion

C# .net 4.0

I have a function

```
 public static void CreateXMLOfCollection(ClassCollection ArraylstObject)
    {
        //Convert array list into List<>  Then pass it for XML Creation: 

        Type classType = AlstObject[0].GetType(); // here is the problem..

        List<classType > lst = ConvertArrayListToList <classType> (AlstObject);



    }


 public static List<T> ConvertArrayListToList<T>(BusinessObjectCollection collection)
 {
      //Code for conversion..
      return lstconvertedArrayList;

 }
```

in `CreateXMLOfCollection` I am not getting how to get the instance of a class, suppose I have a class `Person` then I will write:

```
List<Person> lst = ConvertArrayListToList <Person> (AlstObject); //AlstObject is collection of array list of person class.
```

Can you suggest the generic way to get class instance as `Person` from `ArraylstObject`

here if i Do

```
string className = AlstObject[0].getType().Name; //it gives "Person"
```

Comment: Try to look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-generic-listt

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni, what is "ClassCollection"?

Comment: classCollection is a parent class which is inheriting from arrayList and arrayListCollection will be colletion of child classes, classes which are inherited from classCollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick.

```
public static List<T> ConvertArrayListToList<T>(BusinessObjectCollection collection)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    foreach(object obj in collection)
    {
       try
       {
           T newObj = (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
           list.Add(newObj);
       }
       catch
       {
       }
    }

    return list;
}
```

This also will work the same way.

```
public static List<T> ConvertArrayListToList<T>(BusinessObjectCollection collection)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    foreach(object obj in collection)
    {
       try
       {
           T newObj = (T)obj;
           list.Add(newObj);
       }
       catch
       {
       }
    }

    return list;
}
```