# Copy List to another List, but excluding certain properties of List type

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, anonymous-types

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure out a tidy way to do it.

With the class

```
class SomeType
{ 
   public int SomeInteger {get;}
   public string SomeString {get;}
   public object SomeObject {get;}
}
```

Assuming that a list of SomeType is retrieved from somewhere, but then I need to remove the SomeString field from every item in the list. So I iterate over the list, create an anonymous type and add it to the new list.

```
List<SomeType> list = GetList();

var newList = new List<dynamic>();
list.ForEach(item => newList.Add(new { SomeInteger = item.SomeInteger, SomeObject = item.SomeObject });
```

Is there a better way of doing this that doesn't require me to create an empty list of type dynamic? I could be wrong, but it feels like it's not the best way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the type of T from a generic List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-generic-listt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a list of anonymous types directly, and this will be strongly-typed:

```
list.Select(item => new 
                    { 
                        SomeInteger = item.SomeInteger, 
                        SomeObject = item.SomeObject
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there had to be a nicer way!

Answer (score 3):

You do not need an extra statement to declare `newList`.  The c# compiler can determine the type automagically.  See [Implicitly typed local variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) for more details.

```
 var newList = GetList()
  .Select(x => new { SomeInteger = x.SomeInteger, SomeObject = x.SomeObject})
  .ToList();
```