# Using typeof for a generic object C#

Tags: c#, typeof

How do I get a list of properties for a generic object?

For Example:

```
object OType; 
OType = List<Category>; 
foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in typeof(OType).GetProperties())
{
    Response.Write(prop.Name + "<BR>")
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That would work if I knew the type beforehand, the issue I'm having is that a type will be passed here an I want to get the properties of any type (OType) will be assigned to.

Comment: "the properties of any type (OType) will be assigned to" - what does that mean? Seems like an unbounded set.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly the example is a simplification of your case.

If that is the case consider using **generics**.

```
public void WriteProps<T>()
{
    foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        Response.Write(prop.Name + "<BR>")
    } 
}

...

WriteProps<List<Category>>();
```

Side note:

In your example you are showing type `List<Category>`. The `GetProperties()` will get you [the properties of List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7f69ad7(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want the Category properties check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/557349/1099945).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you *actually* want to do is get properties of a runtime object, without knowing its exact type at compile-time.

Instead of using `typeof` (which is a compile-time constant, basically), use `GetType`:

```
void PrintOutProperties(object OType)
{
  foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in OType.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
      Response.Write(prop.Name + "<BR>")
  } 
}
```

Of course, this only works if `OType` is not null - make sure to include any necessary checks etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `typeof` as with non-generic type? Or `OType` can be assigned at runtime.

```
Type OType = typeof(List<Category>); 
foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in OType.GetProperties())
{
    Response.Write(prop.Name + "<BR>")
}
```

Comment: I am using this as a funtion:L