# Get the type parameter of a Class, by knowing only the Type of Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, abstract, type-parameter

I have a base abstract class having a type parameter from another abstract class, as:

```
public abstract class Database<T> where T : DatabaseItem, new() { //... }

public abstract class DatabaseItem { //... }
```

Then I have number of children classes inherent from it:

```
public class ShopDatabase : Database<ShopItem> {}
public class ShopItem : DatabaseItem {}

public class WeaponDatabase : Database<WeaponItem> {}
public class WeaponItem : DatabaseItem {}

//...
```

Now the problem is, I have an array of *Type* of *Database* as:

```
private static readonly Type[] DATABASE_TYPES = new Type[] {
    typeof (ShopDatabase),
    typeof (WeaponDatabase)
};
```

And I want to get all their type parameters as another array, something like this:

```
Type[] databaseItemTypes = MyFunction (DATABASE_TYPES);
// databaseItemTypes will be an array as: [ShopDatabaseItem, WeaponDatabaseItem]
```

It may be similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-generic-listt) but I don't even have a instance of the Class, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the type arguments for a specific class, that's *relatively* easy:

```
static Type GetDatabaseTypeArgument(Type type)
{
    for (Type current = type; current != null; current = current.BaseType)
    {
        if (current.IsGenericType && current.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Database<>))
        {
            return current.GetGenericTypeArguments()[0];
        }
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Type incompatible with Database<T>");
}
```

Then you can use:

```
Type[] databaseItemTypes = DatabaseTypes.Select(GetDatabaseTypeArgument).ToArray();
```

Note that if you have a class of:

```
public class Foo<T> : Database<T>
```

... then you'll end up getting a `Type` reference representing the `T` in `Foo<T>`. Getting rid of that for a type with a base type of `Foo<string>` for example would be tricky. Hopefully you're not in that situation...