# use a generic type as parameter in C#

Tags: c#, generics

is there a method to tell a method which type a generic has? what i want to do is to tell the method it can be only an object of type A or B but nothing else, so i can work within like

`if (myObject.GetType() == typeof(myTypeA)){doAstuff();}
 if (myObjectGetType() == typeof(myTypeB)) {doBstuff();}`

```
method<T>(T myObject){ T = myTypeA, T = myTypeB, T = nothing else}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Why don't you just have two methods with different parameter types? What do generics bring to this?

Comment: what i want to do is myTypeA and myTypeB share some of the same methods which i want to call, but myTypeB has some more i want to deal with<br> and there is a lot of same stuff so if i make 2 seperate methods i have tons of redundancy which made me make this post, cause that is the old solution

Comment: Are you looking for [`Type.GetGenericArguments()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/557340/3744182)?

Comment: Generics are useless if they apply only to two or three types, that´s why it´s called *generic*. You can however add a constraint to allow only types that implement a common interface for instance.

Comment: do A and B inherit from same class? how come that they share methods?

Comment: Then make two methods, B calls the A and then does something more also? If they're not inheriting or implementing anything common they probably aren't much used even in the methods?

Comment: One solution is to make type specific methods public. `public void Method1<T>() where T : Class2
        {

        }

        public void Method2<T>() where T : Class2
        {

        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the type inside the method, then cast it to the appropriate type and do the appropriate "stuff":

```
public void method<T>(T myObject)
{
    if (myObject is myTypeA)
    {
        myTypeA objA = myObject as myTypeA;
        objA.DoA_Stuff();
    }
    else if (myObject is myTypeB)
    {
        myTypeB objB = myObject as myTypeB;
        objB.DoB_Stuff();
    }
    else
    {
        return ;
    }
}
```

But that would be a waste of generics. If they share some methods you could also make a base class, and let typeA and typeB inherit from it. Then your method could take a base class object as parameter:

```
public void method(BaseClass myObject)
```

and there would be only one if - case and one casting. Only the one with more methods then the base class.

**EDIT:**

Imagine you would have such a structure:

```
public class BaseType
{
    public int SharedProp { get; set; } // shared property 

    public virtual int DoSharedStuff() // shared method
    {
        return SharedProp;
    }    
}

public class myTypeA : BaseType
{
    public int A_Prop { get; set; }

    // overwritten shared meth adjusted to the needs of type A
    public override int DoSharedStuff() 
    {
        return base.SharedProp + this.A_Prop;
    }
}

public class myTypeB : BaseType
{
    public int B_Prop { get; set; }

    // overwritten shared meth adjusted to the needs of type B
    public override int DoSharedStuff()
    {
        return base.SharedProp + this.B_Prop;
    }

    // individual method of Type B
    public int DoB_Stuff()
    {
        return this.B_Prop;
    }
}
```

Then you method would take only one of the children of the base class and execute according to the needs:

```
public void method(BaseType myObject)
{
    // shared case: here type A will perform type A action 
    // and type B will perform type B action
    myObject.DoSharedStuff();

    // case B where you need really the extra stuff!
    if (myObject is myTypeB)
    {
        myTypeB objB = myObject as myTypeB;
        objB.DoB_Stuff();
    }
}
```

This approach or phenomenon is called [Polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism)

Comment: TypeA and TypeB are basically the same, except TypeB has some more Properties, but both objects come from an xml so its hard to have an interface

Comment: I am not talking about interface, you can use simple inheritance, methods are not part of the XML, so you could put the methods into the base class, and overwrite them in the typeClasses. This way they still would be serializable

Comment: yeah i think i will do this, this was a generated XML deserialize class which i was not very fluent with, i guess i will make B inherit A thanks for all the help, i feel stupid

Comment: @Gotti92 I don't know the exact implementation of A and B but yes it might also be a solution to skip the base class. You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the allowed types for a gernic with the where command:

```
public void Test<T>(T param) where T : TypeA {
  ...
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

But this are only simple constraints so it does not solve the problem for two classes but for this case you can use method overloading:

```
public void Test(TypeA param) {
  ...
}
public void Test(TypeB param) {
  ...
}
```

If you have only two classes I think that is the best solution because generics would have no benefits.

Comment: OP states it can be an _object_ of `TypeA` or `TypeB`, so I think `TypeA` and `TypeB` are reference types. If so, this isn't valid C#. You cannot add two reference types to a constraint. This will only work if `TypeA` and `TypeB` are interfaces.

Comment: @ctron that would be the solution, but when i do this TypeB gives me an error saying that it has to be the first, vice versa for TypeA if i turn it, do you know why, or what to do?

Comment: You can't do this unless `TypeA` and `TypeB` are interfaces. This solution is a valid C# syntax. The `,` means `AND` not `OR`. in this context.

Comment: This code won't compile, as there can be only one class type constraint.

Comment: almost correct ... have a base interface say `IType` and both TypeA and TypeB would implement the same. Then you can use that interface for generic constraint

Comment: Sorry my fault this works only with interfaces it can be only one class ... but if you have classes you can overload the method