# How to get the type of object from a DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net, types

I'm within a `Repeater` and I'd like to check out which kind of object its repeating `OnItemDataBound`, but doing this:

```
public void RepeaterListato_OnItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(repeaterListato.DataSource.GetType());
}
```

it returns the whole collection's type:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BrLayer.Pagina]
```

Not `BrLayer.Pagina`. Is there a way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the type of T from a member of a generic class or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-member-of-a-generic-class-or-method)

Comment: @derape, A Repeater is not necessarily bound to a generic collection, so your suggested dupe is inapproriate.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Especially without a helpful comment to explain how to improve the question.

Comment: I downvoted because of the possible dupe. The collection type is of type `List<>` as we can see in your question. It doesn't matter where that list instance lives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnItemDataBound` event handler has an argument `RepeaterItemEventArgs e`.

You want:

```
e.Item.DataItem.GetType()
```

Note that `e.Item.DataItem` will be null if `e.Item.ItemType` is `Header`, `Footer`, `Separator` or `Pager`; so you should check for null or check `ItemType` if your Repeater may have any of these elements.

Note that OnItemDataBound will be called for each item in the DataSource, and that in the general case there is no guarantee that all items will have the same Type.

Comment: typo: its `e.Item.DataItem.GetType()` Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely is possible!  Here's a working example:

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> MyGenericList = new List<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"My list class's type is: {MyGenericList.GetType()}, and its first generic argument is: {MyGenericList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Notice the call to `Type.GetType().GetGenericArguments()`, that's where the magic happens.  It'll return you an array of all the generic arguments of the original type.