# Check if Object is Task or Task<TResult>

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

In the sample code (it does not compile because of the invalid if check) below I need to figure out if returnValue is a "Task of TResult" or a Task or another type. If it's Task of TResult I can access and log the Result property,if it's a Task, there is no return value and I log "[Task]", if it's neither of these two then I can directly log the return value or log a ["null"]

```
public void LogReturnValue(obj returnValue)
{
   var valueToLog = "";
   if(returnValue is Task)
   {
       valueToLog = "[Task]";
   } else if(returnValue is Task<T>)
   {
     valueToLog = returnValue.Result;
   } 
   else 
   {
     valueToLog = returnValue ?? "[null]"
   }
   this.logger.Log(valueToLog);
}
```

> I want to determine if "returnValue" is a Task or "Task of TResult" and if it's the latter, extract the appropriate value from the Result. One
> idea I have is checking the IsGenericType property, but I am not sure
> if that will work always.

Comment: `Task<T>` extends `Task`. If the object is a `Task<T>` then it will pass the first check. The check for generics has to come *before* the test for the non-generic type. But this question implies to me that you are doing something strange and probably wrong; can you say why you want to do this strange thing?

Comment: Also, fetching the result of a task is almost always a *deeply wrong thing to do*. That task might not be completed! You can deadlock your program by doing this! And what if the task is completed with an exception? This will crash your program. Your code doesn't work, but if it did work, it would hang or crash your program much of the time.  **Why are you doing this?**

Comment: @EricLippert If my object is a task, the code outside the context of this question ensures it's a completed task before this method is called, so that is not a concern. If it completed with an exception I can check for that here and log something about it. What I am trying to accomplish is log the returnValue and if there is none, that's fine. The code is just a "SAMPLE CODE", I clearly said that it does not compile, it's just there to help convey what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I understand that it is dangerous to mix async/await with synchronous waits and the resulting deadlock, but this question was just to see how can I at runtime extract the result of a task when the object could be pretty much anything. I fail to understand why people are down-voting it. I think it's reasonable to access the Result as long as you know what you're doing. Again, I know it's not a best practice and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: +1 vote. Typical scenario for me which I use over and over and over again is async runner. I execute some async task in a manner of fire&forget, however runner has `ContinueWith` attached, and then I check the outcome (i.e. faulted, canceled, etc) and display the results in nice manner to the user. Everything is under control and yet I need that `Result`.

Comment: Related: [Cast Task<T> to Task<object> in C# without having T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033760/cast-taskt-to-taskobject-in-c-sharp-without-having-t)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Despite Eric Lippert mentioned that you should not fetch Task.Result, there are a few questions to answer:

1. How to check if an object is a generic type

   ```
   obj.GetType().IsGenericType
   ```
2. Whether it's Task<TResult>

   ```
   obj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>)
   ```
3. How to access a generic property value

   ```
   obj.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(obj) // This value could be null
   ```

Comment: 3. could also be `((dynamic)obj).Result`

Comment: Yes, it works and code is clear, but generated code scares me somehow.

Comment: I was missing #2

Comment: Before someone gets bitten -- in continuations superficially you get Task but second check will fail, you will get result. Textual representation is `"System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult"`.

Comment: Heads up: you _can't_ rely on #2 to determine it's Task<TResult>, depending on the runtime, it might be `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[TResult,TStateMachine]`

Comment: @SaebAmini I'm unsuccessfully trying to reproduce a case where `async` method would return not a task, but an `AsyncStateMachineBox`. Any ideas when this would happen?

Comment: @LaurynasLazauskas may be in case "async Task<>" ?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a cleaner way, but this works and you can build on it.  "as" will check the type or base type is a task, then you can inspect the type to see if it has generic type arguments or not.  Because it's dynamic, the check for Result being a property is done at runtime instead of compile time.

```
static void outType(object returnValue)
{
    dynamic task = returnValue as Task;
    if ( task != null )
    {
        var gargs = returnValue.GetType().GenericTypeArguments;

        if (gargs.Count() == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task");
        }
        else
        {
            var result = task.IsCompleted ? task.Result : "[Not Complete]";
            Console.WriteLine("Task<{0}> : {1}", gargs[0].Name, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has the same problem noted in the comments for the accepted answer. I.e. if the task is actually `Task<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>`, then the code will try to retrieve the `Result` property, but that will fail because `Task<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>` is actually effectively the same as the non-generic `Task` type as far as the task-related parts of the runtime's concerned.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like either none of the preceding answers clearly answered the question being asked, or I rather missed the mark on the intent of the question.

What I interpreted from the question was:

*"How do I tell if 'returnValue' is of Type 'Task', 'Task<>', or something else?*

This test code may be used to determine this:

```
    Task voidTask = new Task(() => { return; });
    Task<object> valTask = new Task<object>(() => { return null; });

    Type voidTaskType = voidTask.GetType();
    Type valTaskType = valTask.GetType();

    Console.WriteLine($"voidTaskType is Task : {voidTask is Task}");
    Console.WriteLine($"valTaskType is Task : {valTask is Task}");
    Console.WriteLine($"voidTaskType.IsGenericType : {voidTaskType.IsGenericType}");
    Console.WriteLine($"valTaskType.IsGenericType : {valTaskType.IsGenericType}");
```

The results are as follows:

```
voidTaskType is Task : True
valTaskType is Task : True
voidTaskType.IsGenericType : False
valTaskType.IsGenericType : True
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it simple, shall we? This method will give you the idea:

```
object GetTaskResult(Task task, out bool hasResult) {
    var resultProperty = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result");
    hasResult = resultProperty != null;
    return hasResult ? resultProperty.GetValue(task) : null;
}
```

It tells you if the task has result and it returns the result if it does.

**Alternative Version**

```
bool GetTaskResult(Task task, out object result) {
    var resultProperty = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result");
    if (resultProperty == null) {
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
    result = resultProperty.GetValue(task);
    return true;
}
```

I've tested it for `VoidTaskResult` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that in **.Net 5** that the null property accessor `?.` is never needed because the **Result** property is present for all tasks. It is initialized to `System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult`. This isn't the most efficient way to get the value, but it is terse.

```
var result = task.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Task<object>.Result))?.GetValue(task);
```

Answer (score -4):

This might help.

Use:

```
Type type = abc.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType
```

Refer to:
[How to get the type of T from a member of a generic class or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-member-of-a-generic-class-or-method)

Comment: that's not gonna work, what if returnValue is not a Task it could be anything else and not necessarily Task<T>

Comment: Did you try both the ways? I'm pretty sure the first one itself is sufficient.

Comment: Var does not work like that either. Unless `obj` is replaced with `string` the code `valueToLog = returnValue;` won't compile

Comment: @Shree what you're essentially saying is if it's not a Task or an IEnumerable then it must be Task<T> ? That is not true, it's okay I think you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: If IEnumerable, enumerate it and check the first item's type.

Comment: Why are you checking for IEnumerable? That has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Done. Added the core logic.