# How to convert a list of generic tasks of different types that are stored in a List<Task>, to a Task<List<object>>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, generics, async-await, task

I am looking to create a `Task<List>` that when invoked with a set of methods executes in parallel, runs and returns the result in the same order of the tasks in an array. The Tasks can return different types. I tried below. Not sure if I am heading in right direction.

```
private async Task<IList<object>> RunTasks<T>(IList<Task> taskList)
{
    var allTasks = Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    var ret = new object[taskList.Count];
    await allTasks;

    for (int i=0;i<taskList.Count;i++)
    {
        ret[i] = taskList[i].IsFaulted ?
            default : ((Task<T>)taskList[i]).Result;
    }
    //otherPolicies.AppsPermissionsPolicy = teamsAppPermissionDocFromAAE
    //    .ToMTTeamsAppPermissionPolicy().ToMTPolicyDocument();
    //Wrap AAE TeamsApp doc response into other Policies
    return ret;
}
```

If `Task1` & `Task2` returns different types in `taskList` do we need `T` for `RunTasks` ? if so, What type do we pass in to Invoke `RunTasks`?. If we dont need it, then how do we convert the Tasks return type to its corresponding object in the for loop immediately after tasks completed before we return the object array with results?

Comment: No way, if we talk except tuples, you have to return object array then cast them respectively in other method. T type is not suitable for it.

Comment: What's wrong with just `return taskList.Select(t => t.Result).ToList();` Also you would need to change the type of your function from `Task<T>` to `Task<List<T>>`

Comment: Updated the code as per the suggestions. Comments please.

Comment: I tried it on a couple of methods returning string & int. when I run it as ` var result = await RunTasks<object>(taskList);` I am seeing below Cast Exception. 
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]'.'

Comment: The `await allTasks;` is going to deal with faulted tasks by throwing the exception of the first non-successful task in the list, so what's the point of checking the `IsFaulted` after that?

Comment: Yeah I guess I started with a very broad problem statement and as I tried different things moving towards more specifics and hence continuous change in title. apologies for this, will mind this going forward. Thank you for your valuable comments @TheodorZoulias

Comment: Although this question is thematically similar to the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033760/cast-taskt-to-taskobject-in-c-sharp-without-having-t) as duplicate, an answer to this question would be off topic if posted as an answer to the other question, and by this criterion they are not exact duplicates. So I am voting to reopen this question.

Comment: Regarding the suitability of the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033760) as a duplicate link of this question, beyond its title *"Cast `Task<T>` to `Task<object>` in C# without having T"* almost everything else in the other question is noise associated with the specific context of that question (`MyContextExtensions`, `DbContext` etc). Someone who would like an answer to *this* question, and only had the other question to work with, would have a hard time composing a solution after filtering out all the noise. This question contains direct answers that are ready to use.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias If you don't like this site's criteria for how duplicates are chosen, that's fine, you can choose not to participate in that system, or you can propose changes to the system such that your own personal criteria are used instead.  What's not appropriate is to use your own criteria in violation of the site's policies.  If you think the answers to the duplicate question contain noise and information irrelevant to the core problem, then you can post your own answer that is more concise and that you feel is more broadly useful to others *with the same question*.

Comment: @Servy don't conflate your criteria and the site's criteria. Be more humble please. Your are just one person, not the whole community.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm not.  The site specifically *doesn't* state that duplicates need to be exact duplicates except in cases where the author is the same and re-asks the *exact* same question (which appears to be the only situation you seem to think it's supposed to be used).  Your criteria is very specifically contrary to the explicitly stated policy and criteria of the site.   I'm not being hubristic, I've simply read the policy.

Comment: @Servy could you share the link where the site's criteria are listed, regarding identification of duplicate questions?

Answer (score 1):

I think that converting a `List<Task>` to a `List<Task<object>>` cannot be done without reflection. Or without the [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) keyword, like in the implementation below:

```
public static Task<object[]> WhenAllToObject(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(tasks);
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(async task =>
    {
        // First await the task, to ensure that it ran successfully.
        await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Then try to get its result, if it's a generic Task<T>.
        try
        {
            return await (dynamic)task;
        }
        catch (Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Non-generic task found.");
        }
    }));
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<Task> heterogeneousListOfTasks = new()
{
    Task.FromResult(13),
    Task.FromResult("Hello"),
    Task.FromResult(true),
};
object[] results = await WhenAllToObject(heterogeneousListOfTasks);
```

---

**Alternative:** This one is inspired by IS4's [ingenious type-matching trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72858214/11178549). The advantage over the above implementation is that the validation of the `tasks` argument happens synchronously. That's because the pattern matching for the `Task` case is a non-`async` method (it [elides async and await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)).

```
public static Task<object[]> WhenAllToObject(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(tasks);
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(task =>
    {
        if (task == null) throw new ArgumentException(
            $"The {nameof(tasks)} argument included a null value.", nameof(tasks));
        Task<object> taskOfObject = ToTaskOfObject((dynamic)task);
        if (taskOfObject == null) throw new ArgumentException(
            $"The {nameof(tasks)} argument included a non-generic Task.", nameof(tasks));
        return taskOfObject;
    }));
}
private static Task<object> ToTaskOfObject(Task task) // Not async
    => null;
private static async Task<object> ToTaskOfObject<T>(Task<T> task)
    => await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Both implementations have similar behavior with the `Task.WhenAll` method, but not identical. The `Task.WhenAll` propagates all exceptions of all tasks. On the contrary the `WhenAllToObject` propagates only the first exception of each task.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Can you pls explain "Generic Task"?  in your example all of them are non generic ones right?(I am assuming Generic Task = operates on Generics. pls correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: @Programmerzzz yes, by generic task I mean a [`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1), and by non-generic task I mean a [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task). The former inherits from the later, so it's always possible to store a `Task<TResult>` instance in a variable of type `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of tasks is 2 (you said task1 and task2) you may consider doing this without a loop:

```
var t1 = DoOneThingAsync();
var t2 = DoAnotherThingAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2); // Without this you can miss exceptions 

var result1 = await t1;
var result2 = await t2;
```

For a dynamic number of tasks I would still suggest separating them by type:

```
List<Task<int>> xs = ...;
List<Task<string>> ys = ...;

var groupX = await Task.WhenAll(xs);
var groupY = await Task.WhenAll(ys);
```

Comment: Now what if you have to repeat this tasks in multiple methods? like say 10 methods need suhch logic of running one or more tasks in parallel. Each of those tasks can have different types dependending on the methods being called from. I know for sure repeating this in 10 diff methods is not optimal. hence looking to reuse so I can just call this from all places.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that in most cases, you shouldn't need this, as once you get the result as `object`, you'll most likely want to cast it back to some concrete type anyway, so why not work with the tasks directly until you are sure what the types are?

Anyway, the non-generic `Task` class doesn't expose the `Result` property like `Task<T>` does, and there aren't any simple workarounds. We'll have to use some tricks!

By far my favourite way is to use `dynamic` combined with overloads, resulting in a sort of runtime type-based pattern matching:

```cs
public static async Task<IEnumerable<object>> TasksResults(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return tasks.Select(t => TaskResult((dynamic)t));
}

static object TaskResult<T>(Task<T> task)
{
    return task.Result;
}

static object TaskResult(Task task)
{
    return null;
}
```

Using `(dynamic)` makes the expression behave as if `t` had actually the most concrete type of the object inside. If it is actually `Task<T>` (with a result), the first overload is chosen, otherwise the second overload is picked. No exception handling necessary.

I've also taken the liberty to use `IEnumerable` for the argument and return type. Feel free to use `.ToList()` if you need to.