# Get generic types of "foreign" class using System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType

Tags: c#

I collect the type of a calling class using:

```
var type = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
```

If the class is of type `SomeType<T>` I want to know the runtime type of `T`, but I can't get it to work.

I have this method that gets the type name which will be called recursively when a type contains generic types. When i run this method with a type I collect using `GetType()` it works and returns for instance `SomeType<Int32>` as string. But when I run the method using `GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType` it will return `SomeType<T>` as string.

My method for creating a type name string:

```
private string GetTypeString(Type type)
{
    var typeString = type.Name;

    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        var genericTypeNames = type.GetGenericArguments().Select(ar => GetTypeString(ar));

        // When a type is generic, it will be formatted as Type`x  (the next line of code will strip the `x)
        var strippedTypeName = typeString.Substring(0, typeString.IndexOf("`"));
        var genericTypeString = string.Join(",", genericTypeNames);
        typeString = $"{strippedTypeName}<{genericTypeString}>";
    }

    return typeString;
}
```

**Example (to show what the result of both methods is):**

```
public class SomeType<T>
{        
}

public static class Main
{
    public void Run()
    {
        SomeType<bool> myClass = new SomeType();

        // This works, but I cannot use it in my application, because I collect the class type using StackFrame
        var type = myClass.GetType();
        var output = GetTypeString(type);  // This returns "SomeType<bool>"

        // This doesn't work:
        type = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
        output = GetTypeString(type);  // This returns "SomeType<T>"
}
```

The first example shows that using `GetType()` gives me the result I want. However I cannot use this, because where I want to create the type string I cannot call GetType() on the class. I get the type using `StackFrame`. The second examples shows the result when I get the type via `GetMethod().DeclaringType'. The outcome is different and not what I am searching for. Does anyone have any tips or suggestions?

**The reality**:

```
public class SomeType<T>
{
    private class Log = new Log();
}

public class Log
{
    private string typeString;

    public Log()
    {
        var type = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType; // This collects type of the calling class, in this case 'SomeType<T>'
        typeString = GetTypeString(type);  // This constructs the type string, but is not able to determine the type of T
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the type of T from a member of a generic class or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-member-of-a-generic-class-or-method)

Comment: @darcane It is a different situation, because I am retrieving the type of the calling class. So I can't use `this.GetType()` or `typeof()`. I updated the post and added the call I make to retrieve the type of the calling class using `StackFrame`.

Comment: You don't need GetType(), you already have the Type.  Rest is the same.  Why you need string parsing is not obvious, just don't do that.  Show any "doesn't work" example.

Comment: @HansPassant I have updated the post with an example showing the case where I get the result I want (but I can't use that in my situation) en the result I get, but want to resolve.

Comment: Very hard to make sense of, the declaring type is Main.  Don't parse strings.

Comment: @HansPassant I instantiate the class `SomeType<T>` as the variable `MyClass` just to show what is working and what is not working. In reality I have a class `A` that is instatiated by `B<T>`. Class `A` wants to log the name of class `B<T>` (including the name of `T`). Class `A` collects the type of class `B<T>` using `StackFrames` and tries to create a string that contains the type name of `B` and the type name of `T`. That's my goal.