# Check difference between List<Guid> and List<Dictionary<string, object>>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to check if I have a Dictionary or Single value like Guid in a List.
Tried Type but only define the Array or Object, anybody has any suggestions?

```
 JArray P = R as JArray;
 try
 {
     JTokenType Type = P.Type;
     Result = P.ToObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {

 }
```

Quick and dirty I thought about to catch the error, but not a nice sight.

Seems info was not correct, the objects are

```
 List<SomeClass>
```

or

```
 List<Guid>
```

Example data:

```
 [
   {
      "Id": "45c41ef8-a030-4480-820d-5bd6bf02bf14",
      "UserId": "246fef1a-e85e-49be-9aad-7d32c8144580",
      "Type": 351208,
      "Name": "*******il.com",
      "isDirect": true,
      "Active": true,
      "History": []
   }
 ]
```

or

```
 ["b0d2dd7d-018c-43ad-9c70-8ec9a3f41978"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm finding it very hard to understand your question. It would be much easier to see what you're trying to do if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You mean given a List<T> you want to find out what T is? [How to get the type of T from a member of a generic class or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/557349/243245)

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and this one is terrible. Trying to ignore a error like this is never going to work out. And you catch way to wide. Here are two articles on Exception Handling that I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | I would be nessesary to know the exception, to tell you proper handling

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is your goal and your difficulty? Please try to better explain your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you're wondering how to check if your List contains Dictionary or not.. But because Dictionary is a generic type, you have to know the specific types of the Dictionary contents if you want to use `is`

i.e. this is your problem:

```
//can't do
if(myList[0] is Dictionary)

//can only do this
if(myList[0] is Dictionary<string, object>)
```

Instead we have to do something like:

```
Type t = myList[0].GetType();
bool isDict = t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>);
```

If you also want to know the types in your dictionary, check the array returned by `t.GetGenericArguments()`

See this fiddle for a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oyyivN

Comment: I just tested it, both return false, for some strange reason

Comment: `myList[0] is Dictionary<string, object>` will return false on a List<Guid> but return true on a `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` - but note that we are testing the type of the first entry in the list - you have to have at least one entry for it to work that way.. Otherwise if your list doesnt have anything inside (0 elements) you'll have to call `GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]` on the List to get the Type of the items it holds, and then query THAT type for IsGeneric etc

Comment: See https://dotnetfiddle.net/oyyivN

Comment: Playing now with your advice, let you know what I come up with

Comment: The .GetGenericArguments()[0] gives the error for a strange reason ...I copied the List<SomeClass> in queston

Comment: Can you reproduce it? I tried with a non-dictionary argument too, but couldn't https://dotnetfiddle.net/rwQKjy

Comment: Error is {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}, also the data is wrapped in a object

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenericarguments?view=netframework-4.8 says *Returns An array of Type objects that represent the type arguments of a generic type. **Returns an empty array if the current type is not a generic type.**..* - so the reason [0] is out of bounds is because the returned array is empty, because the thing you're querying isn't a List<T>?

Comment: No it not returns empty, I copied a sample set in the question, otherwise I would understand it

Comment: Not really sure what to suggest; investigate the object you have in the Locals/Immediate window of the debugger?

Comment: The problem is that it does not have a key/value and only a value, so for now I will block the only value one, but thx for your help and idd I tested your solution it worked

Comment: Not quite sure how a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can have only a key and not a value - that sounds like a HashSet<T>? But glad you got something going! :)

Comment: @user3763117: That sounds like a Bag, Set, Queue, Stack or similar Key-& Indexless collection. In wich case you always wanted the value, not the key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a single `List<T>`, it is just plain old [Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains).

The second case is harder, for multiple reasons:

1. Because you got a *List* of Dictionaties. So you have to itterate over the List Elements to even get to the thing that has the data or key you want.
2. Because you got a List of *Dictionaries*. Wich means you have to decide if you want to use ContainsKey() or ContainsValue() checks.

It would help a lot if we had some actuall examples for those types. This is not enough to give you more then a general direction.

P.S.: Please never use object as type in a generic class. It ruins type saftey. As a mater of fact, Generics were introduced so we finally could **stop** using object. We still have those pre-generic collections floating around the Namespaces, like ghosts of the past.

Comment: Yeah but its and internal handler, not really a fan also from dynamic and those fancey stuff). I am not sure if I solve the problem with on contains as the Dictionary contains variable keys which I have no idea off.

Comment: @user3763117 It is not clear what you even want to find in those Collections. It does not help that both have utterly different types.