# Using generics to get correct return type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to generate a filter with a generic method. Filter is an abstract class. SomeFilter class would extend Filter. I want a method like this:

```
protected Filter GenerateFilter<T> () where T : Filter
{
    if (T == SomeFilter) 
    {
        return new SomeFilter();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I'm new to C#, coming from Java. These solutions have helped me a lot in understanding C# generics. Thanks for the help. I will indeed proceed with a FilterFactory. I had hoped i might be able to pull it off with generics, but a factory is still the better thing to implement here.

Thanks!

Comment: `return new T()`?..

Comment: Sounds more like the need for a FilterFactory.

Comment: This should get you the answer you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-member-of-a-generic-class-or-method

Comment: Why do you need `GenerateFilter` at all? Why can't you just do `Filter f = new SomeFilter();` instead of `Filter f = FilterFactory.GenerateFilter<SomeFilter>()`?

Comment: A generic method should *be generic*, which is to say you should be able to use *any type*, not just a single type, or one of a small fixed list of types.  If you want a single type, or one from a small set, you shouldn't use generic and just have a method for each type.

Comment: What is the problem with the code in the example? `if (typeof(T) == typeof(SomeFilter))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the new() constraint to the T type parameter and change you method like so:

```
protected Filter GenerateFilter<T>() where T : Filter, new()
{
        return new T();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflection to create instance

```
protected Filter GenerateFilter<T>() where T : Filter
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at checking for each individual case

```
    public static T Generate<T>() where T: Filter
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        if (t == typeof(SomeFilter))
        {
            return new SomeFilter() as T;
        }
        if (t == typeof(OtherFilter))
        {
            return new OtherFilter() as T;
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

which can be part of a class hierarchy with known types.

This is going to fall flat if the filters come from a plug-in situation which means not all concrete types are known at compile time. That would require a different architecture, which the *op* hasn't stated is required.

---

An alternate solution is each concrete type has a default constructor, is to use `new()`

```
    public static T Generate<T>() where T: Filter, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
```

---

A third option is to use a deferred type in the filter class just a follows:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeFilter filter = Filter<SomeFilter>.Generate();
        SomeFilter also = filter.Copy();
        filter.Combine(also);
    }
}


public abstract class Filter<TFilter> where TFilter: Filter<TFilter>, new()
{
    public static TFilter Generate() 
    {
        return new TFilter();
    }

    public TFilter Copy() => this.MemberwiseClone() as TFilter;

    public abstract void Combine(TFilter other);
}
public class SomeFilter : Filter<SomeFilter>
{
    public float Alpha { get; set; }

    public override void Combine(SomeFilter other)
    {
        this.Alpha *= other.Alpha;
    }
}
public class OtherFilter : Filter<OtherFilter>
{
    public int Strength { get; set; }

    public override void Combine(OtherFilter other)
    {
        this.Strength = Math.Max(Strength, other.Strength);
    }
}
```

The advantage of the base class to know the type of the derived class in `TFilter` is that it cam be used in methods, such as `Combine()` and `Copy()` above and it will resolve to the correct type when implemented.